# SELECT id HAVING maximum count of id

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, having-clause

Have a products table with item_id and color_id.  I'm trying to get the color_id with the most non-null instances.

This fails:

```
SELECT color_id 
  FROM products 
 WHERE item_id=1234 
 GROUP BY item_id 
HAVING MAX(COUNT(color_id))
```

with

```
Invalid use of group function
```

This

```
SELECT color_id, COUNT(color_id)
  FROM products 
 WHERE item_id=1234 
 GROUP BY item_id
```

Returns

```
color_id count
1, 323
2, 122
3, 554
```

I am looking for color_id 3, which has the most instances.

Is there a quick and easy way of getting what I want without 2 queries?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
SELECT color_id AS id, COUNT(color_id) AS count 
FROM products 
WHERE item_id = 1234 AND color_id IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY color_id 
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This will give you the color_id and the count on that color_id ordered by the count from greatest to least. I think this is what you want.

---

for your edit...

```
SELECT color_id, COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE color_id = 3;
```

Comment: You should add a `limit 1` to answer the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff `limit 1`. what if there are multiple instances having the same *greatest* count?

Comment: consider this result, `1, 100`, `2, 100`, `3, 50`.

Comment: @JW Depeneds on the context. maybe you don't care if there are ties for the max... maybe you do...

Comment: I think this would be a logic problem on my end.. what to show.

Comment: I need to assign an importance to each color_id and let that be the tie breaker.

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT color_id
FROM
    (
        SELECT  color_id, COUNT(color_id) totalCount
        FROM    products 
        WHERE   item_id = 1234 
        GROUP   BY color_id 
    ) s
HAVING totalCount = MAX(totalCount)
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  color_id, COUNT(color_id) totalCount
FROM    products 
WHERE   item_id = 1234 
GROUP   BY color_id 
HAVING  COUNT(color_id) =
(
  SELECT  COUNT(color_id) totalCount
  FROM    products 
  WHERE   item_id = 1234 
  GROUP   BY color_id 
  ORDER BY totalCount DESC
  LIMIT 1  
)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*having tie*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b660/5)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
  color_id, 
  COUNT(color_id) AS occurances
FROM so_test
GROUP BY color_id
ORDER BY occurances DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

Here is a sample fiddle with a basic table that shows it working: [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcced/1)

Comment: fantastic, this is what I was looking for,

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple, use in built function in Oracle(Works only with Oracle Database 11g+ version) :

```
select stats_mode(color_id) from so_test
```

This would return highest occurrence of colour ids.