# Get the most active users from an 'actions' table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table for actions conducted by my users, the 'email' column in that table specifies which user did what. What I want to do is run a query to find the most active user based on the amount of actions containing his email. That is, I want the query to return the email that is most present in my table. I've hit a wall trying to figure out how to do this, any idea?

```
ID  EMAIL   ACTION
1   tester@gmail.com    deletion
2   tester@gmail.com    addition
3   tester@gmail.com    modification
4   tester@gmail.com    deletion
5   not_a_tester@gmail.com    deletion
6   someone_else@gmail.com    deletion
7   another_guy@gmail.com    deletion
8   not_a_tester@gmail.com    deletion
```

Should return tester@gmail.com in this instance.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I have added a sample

Comment: In this case, GROUP BY returned the email of someone with two actions, who also happens to be the first ID on the database ,as opposed to someone else who has 3.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249689/select-id-having-maximum-count-of-id

Comment: @GordonLinoff pls check out the duplicate link and hammer if you think it is appropriate

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(email) AS maxcount,email 
from table_name 
group by email
having MAX(count(email))
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please *explain* what you have done.

Comment: What i have simply done is to group the emails and get the count.  The return the most frequent email in the having clause.

Comment: put it in your answer, not as a comment to your answer.