# Calculate contribution

Tags: sql, sql-server

It is not legal to do `max(count())`, so how do I accomplish calculating the contribution as shown here (and also get the other columns)

```
SELECT id,
       Avg(time)      AS avgSec,
       Stdev(time)    AS stdevSec,
       Count(time)    AS cnt,
       Avg(time)*Count(time)/max(Count(time))  AS contribution
FROM ...very long and complex query...
```

Comment: Maybe duplicated : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436820/can-i-do-a-maxcount-in-sql

Comment: What is the formula for contribution

Comment: I do not want to repeat the very long and complex query

Comment: @Prdp `avg * cnt / max(cnt)` as mentioned in the sql

Comment: You have count(time) function, but you are not aggregating on any thing and since you will get a single count values. No point in taking max for a single value. Have a group by clause, which provides you an expected result

Comment: I don't understand what is the point. What are you looking for with `max(count` ? What means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MAX()OVER()` window aggregate function to get maximum count out of all records

Here is the correct way

```
Avg(time)*Count(time)/max(Count(time)) over()
```

Comment: Over() is working as you wrote first. Over(partition) gives wrong result

Comment: @Cine - ok, May be I over looked it