# Create new table based on max count per id

Tags: sql, select

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID  Code    Count
A     AA    10
A     BB    7
B     AA    7
B     BB    10
C     CC    10
C     DD    7
```

I was wondering how I could select each id with the highest count?

I tried using this code as a reference, but am having no luck: [Can I do a max(count(*)) in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436820/can-i-do-a-maxcount-in-sql)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways.  Here is one:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.count = (select max(t2.count) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

Comment: I receive this error `cannot recognize input near 'select' 'max' '(' in expression specification (state=42000,code=40000)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do `max(count(*))` via splitting into 2 levels:

```
select id, max(cnt) as max_cnt
from (select id, count(*) as cnt from table group by id) as a
group by id
```