# Get top row(s) with highest value, with ties

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-limit

I have a relation in PostgreSQL named `product` which contains 2 fields: `id` and `quantity`.

I want to find the `id` of the products with the highest `quantity`. As far as I know, there are 2 ways of doing it:

```sql
SELECT id FROM product WHERE quantity >= ALL(SELECT quantity FROM product)
```

or

```sql
SELECT id FROM product WHERE quantity = (SELECT MAX(quantity) FROM product)
```

Is there any difference in their speed of execution?

Comment: When you try both queries, which one runs faster?

Comment: @GMB I get just the same results at the same time, but I doubt that select the max quantity first will give me more advantage when talking about time

Comment: Test, Test, Test, and get explain plans. Unless your first query turns out to be *significantly* faster go with the second (select max...). It seems that it more clearly indicates your intent (IMHO anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first query fails if any row has `quantity IS NULL` (as [Gordon demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63179321/939860)).
The second query only fails if all rows have `quantity IS NULL`. So it should be usable in most cases. (And it's faster.)

#### Postgres 13 or newer

Use the standard SQL clause [**`WITH TIES`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT):

```sql
SELECT id
FROM   product
ORDER  BY quantity DESC NULLS LAST
FETCH  FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=47f07b0263e1d6764583b7a19fb30d55)*

Works with any amount of `NULL` values.

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT)

> SQL:2008 introduced a different syntax to achieve the same result,
> which PostgreSQL also supports. It is:
>
> ```
> OFFSET start { ROW | ROWS }
> FETCH { FIRST | NEXT } [ count ] { ROW | ROWS } { ONLY | WITH TIES }
> ```
>
> In this syntax, the ***`start`*** or ***`count`*** value is required by the standard
> to be a literal constant, a parameter, or a variable name; as a
> PostgreSQL extension, other expressions are allowed, but will
> generally need to be enclosed in parentheses to avoid ambiguity. If
> ***`count`*** is omitted in a `FETCH` clause, it defaults to 1. The `WITH TIES`
> option is used to return any additional rows that tie for the last
> place in the result set according to the `ORDER BY` clause; `ORDER BY` is
> mandatory in this case. `ROW` and `ROWS` as well as `FIRST` and `NEXT` are
> noise words that don't influence the effects of these clauses.

Notably, `WITH TIES` cannot be used with the (non-standard) short syntax `LIMIT n`.

It's the **fastest possible solution**. Faster than either of your current queries. More important for **performance**: have an **index** on `(quantity)`. Or a more specialized covering index to allow index-only scans (a bit faster, yet):

```
CREATE INDEX ON product (quantity DESC NULLS LAST) INCLUDE (id);
```

See:

- [Do covering indexes in PostgreSQL help JOIN columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/190151/3684)

We need `NULLS LAST` to keep `NULL` values last in descending order. See:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)

#### Postgres 12 or older

A NULL-safe query:

```sql
SELECT id, quantity
FROM   product
WHERE  quantity IS NOT DISTINCT FROM (SELECT MAX(quantity) FROM product);
```

Or, probably faster:

```sql
SELECT id, quantity
FROM  (
   SELECT *, rank() OVER (ORDER BY quantity DESC NULLS LAST) AS rnk
   FROM   product
   ) sub
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

See:

- [PostgreSQL equivalent for TOP n WITH TIES: LIMIT "with ties"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629953/postgresql-equivalent-for-top-n-with-ties-limit-with-ties/9630562#9630562)

Faster alternatives for big tables:

- [Equivalent for FETCH FIRST WITH TIES in PostgreSQL 11 with comparable performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074473/equivalent-for-fetch-first-with-ties-in-postgresql-11-with-comparable-performanc/71074731#71074731)

Answer (score 1):

I tried your methods in postgres (test table distributed by id). That first method ran much slower for me. Here were my comparison results:

Method 1 above: 3.1 seconds

Method 2 above: 0.13 seconds

Method 1 was at least 10 times slower in repeated efforts. I think your method 2 is the better option, as the sub-query likely runs much faster than the sub-query in the other option.

Comment: Thank you. Can you give me more details on the size of the table that you worked on? I tried the above query with a small table and could not see the differences in running time

Comment: The table was 2 columns, with somewhere between 900,000 and 3 million rows. I don't recall for certain.

Answer (score 1):

Your queries are NOT equivalent.  The first returns no rows at all if *any* of the `quantity` values are `NULL`.  The second ignores `NULL` values.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a2344b0684fe1f129ced8139b450bf9a) is a db<>fiddle illustrating this.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that. If all of the quantity values are not NULL, which should be the faster one?

Comment: @ĐàoMinhDũng . . . I think Isolated answered that question.

Answer (score 1):

there is the 3rd variant

```
SELECT id FROM product 
WHERE quantity = (SELECT quantity FROM product ORDER BY quantity DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 1)
```

if the table has btree index as (quantity DESC NULLS LAST) this variant will be super-fast