# Fetching a minimum of N rows, plus all peers of the last row

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-limit

I have a sample table named assets which looks like this:

| id | name | block_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | asset1 | 2 |
| 2 | asset2 | 2 |
| 3 | asset3 | 3 |

There can be any number of assets in a specific block. I need a minimum of 100 rows from the table, and containing all the data from the `block_no`. Like, if there are 95 rows to `block_no` 2 and around 20 on `block_no` 3, I need all 20 of `block_no` 3 as if I am fetching data in packets based on `block_no`.
Is this possible and feasible?

Comment: It is very possible, use length and where commands to complete it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Postgres 13 or later

There is a dead simple solution using [**`WITH TIES`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT) in **Postgres 13** or later:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   assets
WHERE  block_no >= 2  -- your starting block
ORDER  BY block_no
FETCH  FIRST 100 ROWS WITH TIES;
```

This will return *at least* 100 rows (if enough qualify), plus all peers of the 100th row.

If your table isn't trivially small, an index on `(block_no)` is essential for performance.

See:

- [Get top row(s) with highest value, with ties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63178114/get-top-rows-with-highest-value-with-ties/63184287#63184287)

#### Older versions

Use the window function `rank()` in a subquery:

```sql
SELECT (a).*
FROM  (
   SELECT a, rank() OVER (ORDER BY block_no) AS rnk
   FROM   assets a
   ) sub
WHERE  rnk <= 100;
```

Same result.

I use a little trick with the row type to strip the added `rnk` from the result. That's an optional addition.

See:

- [PostgreSQL equivalent for TOP n WITH TIES: LIMIT "with ties"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629953/postgresql-equivalent-for-top-n-with-ties-limit-with-ties/9630562#9630562)