# How to return the category with max value for every user in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is the table

| id | category | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 40 |
| 1 | B | 20 |
| 1 | C | 10 |
| 2 | A | 4 |
| 2 | B | 7 |
| 2 | C | 7 |
| 3 | A | 32 |
| 3 | B | 21 |
| 3 | C | 2 |

I want the result like this

| id | category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | A |

Comment: You could refer to some topic with `SELECT value WITH MAX...`, for [e.g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432913/select-info-from-table-where-row-has-max-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small tables or for only *very few* rows per user, a subquery with the window function `rank()` (as [demonstrated by The Impaler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69922931/939860)) is just fine. The resulting sequential scan over the whole table, followed by a sort will be the most efficient query plan.

For more than a few rows per user, this gets increasingly inefficient though.

Typically, you also have a `users` table holding one distinct row per user. If you don't have it, created it! See:

- [Is there a way to SELECT n ON (like DISTINCT ON, but more than one of each)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/133418/3684)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

We can leverage that for an alternative query that scales *much* better - using `WITH TIES` in a `LATERAL JOIN`. Requires **Postgres 13** or later.

```sql
SELECT u.id, t.*
FROM   users u
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT t.category
   FROM   tbl t
   WHERE  t.id = u.id
   ORDER  BY t.value DESC
   FETCH  FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES  -- !
   ) t;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7ee614e5feb255b03227aec414ae5516)*

See:

- [Get top row(s) with highest value, with ties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63178114/get-top-rows-with-highest-value-with-ties/63184287#63184287)
- [Fetching a minimum of N rows, plus all peers of the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69907093/fetching-a-minimum-of-n-rows-plus-all-peers-of-the-last-row/69907406#69907406)

This can use a multicolumn **index** to great effect - which must exist, of course:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl (id, value);
```

Or:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl (id, value DESC);
```

Even faster [**index-only scans**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) become possible with:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl (id, value DESC, category);
```

Or (the optimum for the query at hand):

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl (id, value DESC) INCLUDE (category);
```

Assuming `value` is defined `NOT NULL`, or we have to use `DESC NULLS LAST`. See:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)

To keep users in the result that don't have any rows in table `tbl`, user `LEFT JOIN LATERAL (...) ON true`. See:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RANK()` to identify the rows you want. Then, filtering is easy. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select *,
    rank() over(partition by id order by value desc) as rk
  from t
) x
where rk = 1
```

Result:

```
 id  category  value  rk 
 --- --------- ------ -- 
 1   A         40     1  
 2   B         7      1  
 2   C         7      1  
 3   A         32     1
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pcdHLess1yFwBUWSQasZta/0).

Comment: I get  'WITHIN GROUP is required for ordered-set aggregate rank' result

Comment: @Erik Works well, see example. Are you sure you are using PostgreSQL? `WITHIN GROUP` is a clause that can be typically found in Oracle or DB2.

Comment: Sorry that was my fault, and your code is working, thanks for sharing