# Equivalent for FETCH FIRST WITH TIES in Postgres 11 with comparable performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11, sql-limit

Given the following DDL

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (
    id     BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    number BIGINT
);
CREATE INDEX ON numbers (number);
```

In PostgreSQL 13 I can use the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM numbers
WHERE number > 1
ORDER BY number
FETCH FIRST 1000 ROWS WITH TIES
```

It produces a very effective query plan and performs well enough with large tables:

```
Limit  (cost=...)                                                   
  ->  Index Scan using numbers_number_idx on numbers  (cost=...) 
        Index Cond: (number > 1)
```

Is there an equivalent for that in PostgreSQL 11 that gives a similar query plan and comparable performance for large (10TB+) tables?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9630562/4624905) suggests to use the following query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY number) AS rnk
    FROM numbers
    WHERE number > 1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rnk <= 1000;
```

But it is not really usable for large tables because performance is many times worse.

```
Subquery Scan on cte  (cost=...)                                       
  Filter: (cte.rnk <= 1000)                                                                       
  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=...)                                            
        ->  Index Scan using numbers_number_idx on numbers  (cost=...) 
              Index Cond: (number > 1)
```

Comment: Asides: the physical size of the table (`10TB+`) is not as relevant as the number of rows. The index only cares about the number of rows, not their width. And don't forget: upgrading to a current version is the best option. `WITH TIES` is not the only benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't get the performance of the extremely convenient `WITH TIES` in **Postgres 13** or later. See:

- [Get top row(s) with highest value, with ties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63178114/get-top-rows-with-highest-value-with-ties/63184287#63184287)

But there are always options ...

#### Faster SQL variant

Should be faster **for big tables** because it avoids to rank the whole table like the [simple solution in the referenced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9630562/939860).

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *, row_number() OVER (ORDER  BY number, id) AS rn  -- ORDER must match
   FROM   numbers
   WHERE  number > 1
   ORDER  BY number, id  -- tiebreaker to make it deterministic
   LIMIT  1000
   )
TABLE cte
UNION ALL
(
SELECT n.*, 1000 + row_number() OVER (ORDER BY n.id) AS rn
FROM   numbers n, (SELECT number, id FROM cte WHERE rn = 1000) AS max
WHERE  n.number = max.number
AND    n.id > max.id
ORDER  BY n.id
);
```

`id` is any `UNIQUE NOT NULL` column in your table that lends itself as tiebreaker, typically the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Sort by that *additionally*, which has the (maybe welcome) side effect that you get a deterministically ordered result.

Ideally, you have a multicolumn **index** on `(number, id)` for this. But it will use the existing index on just `(number)`, too. Resulting performance depends on cardinalities and data types.
Related:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

Since the CTE query counts as *one* command, there is **no race condition** under concurrent write load. All parts of the command see the same snapshot of the table in default isolation level `READ COMMITTED`.

I might wrap this into a simple SQL function (or prepared statement) and pass `LIMIT` to it for convenience.

#### Alternative with PL/pgSQL

Only running a single `SELECT` probably outweighs the added overhead. Works optimally with the existing index on just `(number)`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(_bound int, _limit int, OUT _row public.numbers)
  RETURNS SETOF public.numbers
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _ct int := 0;
   _number int;  -- match type!
BEGIN
   FOR _row IN
      SELECT *
      FROM   public.numbers
      WHERE  number > _bound
      ORDER  BY number
   LOOP
      _ct := _ct + 1;
      CASE 
      WHEN _ct < _limit THEN
         -- do nothing
      WHEN _ct > _limit THEN
         EXIT WHEN _row.number > _number;
      WHEN _ct = _limit THEN
         _number := _row.number;   
      END CASE;

      RETURN NEXT;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

But it's tailored for just the one query. Gets tedious for varying queries.

Comment: In my setup an additional `(number, PK)` index would be a big trade off so I was hoping that maybe there's a solution that would utilize `(number)` index.

Comment: The solution *will* use an index on `(number)` (while cardinality in the column isn't *very* low), but one on `(number, PK)` - or any unique not null column - will be faster, as long as the index is not *much* bigger. Also, the multicolumn index is good for *everything* that first index is. It just shouldn't be much bigger. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684

Comment: what is the purpose of `TABLE cte` in `WITH cte AS (...) TABLE cte ...`

Comment: @HaleemurAli: It's short syntax for `SELECT * FROM cte`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30276023/939860

Answer (score 2):

I got pretty good results with the following select query. Not as fast as the other answer, but the query is also a lot simpler. the offset value has to be 1 less than the number of rows desired (999 for 1000) since offset starts at 0.

```sql
-- query 1
select *
from numbers 
where number <= (
  select number 
  from numbers
  where number > 1
  order by number
  offset 999 limit 1
  ) 
  and number > 1
```

---

#### Performance

test was run with the table as defined in the question, and the following insert statement.

```sql
INSERT INTO numbers (n) 
SELECT floor(random() * 100000000) 
FROM generate_series(1, 100000000);
```

*I'll admit its not very scientific, as this is done on my puny windows 10 laptop & running on a postgresql 13 cluster on wsl with all default settings on battery power. i didn't restart the server between runs or do anything to prevent optimization due to data present in cache.*

Explain analyze results, where query 1 refers to the query above, query 2 refers to the simple query in question, query 3 refers to query in other answer and query 4 is the elegant `with ties` variant.

| query | execution time | factor slower |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 80.642 ms | 63.6 |
| 2 | 142142.026 ms | 112011 |
| 3 | 59.551 ms | 46.9 |
| 4 | 1.269 ms | 1 |

---

#### Explain analyze query plans

```
-- query 1
 Gather  (cost=10965.26..1178206.10 rows=500000 width=16) (actual time=64.157..79.186 rows=1000 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Params Evaluated: $0
   Workers Launched: 2
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Limit  (cost=27.66..27.69 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=63.613..63.615 rows=1 loops=1)
           ->  Index Only Scan using numbers_n_idx on numbers numbers_1  (cost=0.57..2712066.05 rows=100000085 width=8) (actual time=0.029..0.318 rows=1000 loops=1)
                 Index Cond: (number > 1)
                 Heap Fetches: 0
   ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on numbers  (cost=9937.57..1127178.41 rows=208333 width=16) (actual time=0.090..0.498 rows=333 loops=3)
         Recheck Cond: ((number <= $0) AND (number > 1))
         Heap Blocks: exact=1000
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on numbers_n_idx  (cost=0.00..9812.57 rows=500000 width=0) (actual time=0.135..0.135 rows=1000 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((number <= $0) AND (number > 1))
 Planning Time: 0.230 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 18
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 1.936 ms, Inlining 44.863 ms, Optimization 12.045 ms, Emission 6.182 ms, Total 65.026 ms
 Execution Time: 80.642 ms
(20 rows)
```

```
-- query 2
 Subquery Scan on cte  (cost=8472029.70..22868689.85 rows=33333362 width=24) (actual time=40001.966..142074.323 rows=1000 loops=1)
   Filter: (cte.rnk <= 1000)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 99998999
   ->  WindowAgg  (cost=8472029.70..21618688.79 rows=100000085 width=24) (actual time=40001.964..129209.141 rows=99999999 loops=1)
         ->  Gather Merge  (cost=8472029.70..20118687.52 rows=100000085 width=16) (actual time=40001.921..75176.460 rows=99999999 loops=1)
               Workers Planned: 2
               Workers Launched: 2
               ->  Sort  (cost=8471029.68..8575196.43 rows=41666702 width=16) (actual time=39707.316..46741.888 rows=33333333 loops=3)
                     Sort Key: numbers.number
                     Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 856888kB
                     Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 839696kB
                     Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 847688kB
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on numbers  (cost=0.00..1061374.79 rows=41666702 width=16) (actual time=60.334..13404.824 rows=33333333 loops=3)
                           Filter: (number > 1)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 0
 Planning Time: 0.179 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 16
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 1.773 ms, Inlining 90.193 ms, Optimization 55.148 ms, Emission 34.709 ms, Total 181.823 ms
 Execution Time: 142142.026 ms
(21 rows)
```

```
-- query 3
 Append  (cost=2497.62..2628.54 rows=1005 width=24) (actual time=12.881..59.360 rows=1000 loops=1)
   CTE cte
     ->  Limit  (cost=1004.33..2497.62 rows=1000 width=24) (actual time=12.877..58.683 rows=1000 loops=1)
           ->  WindowAgg  (cost=1004.33..149329948.33 rows=100000085 width=24) (actual time=12.875..58.435 rows=1000 loops=1)
                 ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1004.33..147579946.84 rows=100000085 width=16) (actual time=12.858..57.988 rows=1001 loops=1)
                       Workers Planned: 2
                       Workers Launched: 2
                       ->  Incremental Sort  (cost=4.31..136036455.76 rows=41666702 width=16) (actual time=0.147..29.746 rows=366 loops=3)
                             Sort Key: numbers.number, numbers.id
                             Presorted Key: numbers.number
                             Full-sort Groups: 13  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 26kB  Peak Memory: 26kB
                             Worker 0:  Full-sort Groups: 15  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 26kB  Peak Memory: 26kB
                             Worker 1:  Full-sort Groups: 8  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 26kB  Peak Memory: 26kB
                             ->  Parallel Index Scan using numbers_n_idx on numbers  (cost=0.57..134359882.50 rows=41666702 width=16) (actual time=0.042..29.576 rows=393 loops=3)
                                   Index Cond: (number > 1)
   ->  CTE Scan on cte  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=24) (actual time=12.880..14.618 rows=1000 loops=1)
   ->  WindowAgg  (cost=105.75..105.85 rows=5 width=24) (actual time=0.079..0.081 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=105.75..105.76 rows=5 width=16) (actual time=0.077..0.079 rows=0 loops=1)
               Sort Key: n.id
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..105.69 rows=5 width=16) (actual time=0.070..0.071 rows=0 loops=1)
                     ->  CTE Scan on cte cte_1  (cost=0.00..22.50 rows=5 width=16) (actual time=0.051..0.051 rows=1 loops=1)
                           Filter: (rn = 1000)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 999
                     ->  Index Scan using numbers_n_idx on numbers n  (cost=0.57..16.63 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.015..0.016 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (number = cte_1.number)
                           Filter: (id > cte_1.id)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Planning Time: 0.202 ms
 Execution Time: 59.551 ms
(30 rows)
```

```
-- query 4
Limit  (cost=0.57..1350.00 rows=1000 width=16) (actual time=0.013..1.113 rows=1000 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using numbers_n_idx on numbers  (cost=0.57..134943216.33 rows=100000085 width=16) (actual time=0.012..0.869 rows=1001 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (number > 1)
 Planning Time: 0.142 ms
 Execution Time: 1.269 ms
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Always nice to see a performance test! One note: `floor(random() * 100000000)` generates very few duplicates. Comparison to a case with more duplicates would be interesting. I'd expect the added PL/pgSQL solution to be fastest in either scenario - behind `WITH TIES`, or course.