# Solution without LIMIT

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-limit

I have a table like this (from LeetCode):

| requester_id | accepter_id | accept_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2016/06/03 |
| 1 | 3 | 2016/06/08 |
| 2 | 3 | 2016/06/08 |
| 3 | 4 | 2016/06/09 |

Find the people who have the most friends and the most friends number.

Expected Output:

| id | num |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 |

I wrote this query for the answer and it works:

```
select a.f as "id", count(a.f) as "num"
from (
    select requester_id as f
    from requestaccepted
    union all
    select accepter_id as f
    from requestaccepted ) a
group by a.f
order by count(a.f) desc
limit 1;
```

I am not 100% convinced using `limit 1` is the best solution.

**What should be an alternative/better option?**

Comment: *"Find the people who have ... "* would indicate that you return *all* winners (in case multiple share the maximum), not just a single one. But if you want a single one, then define how to pick it - what's the tiebreaker?

Answer (score 3):

`LIMIT 1` after `ORDER BY` is just fine to get a **single** winner:

```sql
SELECT a.id, count(*) AS num
FROM  (
   SELECT requester_id AS id FROM requestaccepted
   UNION ALL
   SELECT accepter_id  AS id FROM requestaccepted
   ) a
GROUP  BY a.id
ORDER  BY num DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

You get an arbitrary pick if there are multiple winners. You might add additional `ORDER BY` expressions to get a deterministic pick.

If you must avoid `LIMIT` / `FETCH FIRST` (really?) the window function `row_number()` is a (more expensive!) alternative:

```sql
SELECT id, num
FROM  (
   SELECT a.id, count(*) AS num
        , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS rn
   FROM  (
      SELECT requester_id AS id FROM requestaccepted
      UNION ALL
      SELECT accepter_id  AS id FROM requestaccepted
      ) a
   GROUP BY a.id
   ) sub
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

To get **all** IDs that tie for the win, just add `WITH TIES`. Must use standard SQL syntax `FETCH  FIRST 1 ROWS` instead of the Postgres shortcut `LIMIT 1` to add the clause.

```sql
SELECT a.id, count(*) AS num
FROM  (
   SELECT requester_id AS id FROM requestaccepted
   UNION ALL
   SELECT accepter_id  AS id FROM requestaccepted
   ) a
GROUP  BY a.id
ORDER  BY count(*) DESC
FETCH  FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES;
```

No additional `ORDER BY` expressions, that would resolve ties.

If you must avoid `LIMIT` / `FETCH FIRST` (really?) the window function `rank()` is a (more expensive!) alternative:

```sql
SELECT id, num
FROM  (
   SELECT a.id, count(*) AS num
       , rank() OVER (ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS rnk
   FROM  (
      SELECT requester_id AS id FROM requestaccepted
      UNION ALL
      SELECT accepter_id  AS id FROM requestaccepted
      ) a
   GROUP  BY a.id
   ) sub
WHERE  rnk = 1
ORDER  BY id; -- optional
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=dbb38c75b036bd8af5657ddfdf990d38)* - with extended test case to show a tie

See:

- [Get top row(s) with highest value, with ties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63178114/get-top-rows-with-highest-value-with-ties/63184287#63184287)
- [PostgreSQL equivalent for TOP n WITH TIES: LIMIT "with ties"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629953/postgresql-equivalent-for-top-n-with-ties-limit-with-ties/9630562#9630562)

Answer (score 0):

As you just need friends with highest count, you can directly get count of accepted id, and max of that will work.

```
select  id ,max(num) from
(
select accepter_id id ,count(*) num from requestaccepted
group by accepter_id 
) a
```

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting way could be using `Join Lateral` with `Limit`

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table requestaccepted(requester_id int, accepter_id int, accept_date date);
 insert into requestaccepted values(1,  2,  '2016/06/03');
 insert into requestaccepted values(1,  3,  '2016/06/08');
 insert into requestaccepted values(2,  3,  '2016/06/08');
 insert into requestaccepted values(3,  4,  '2016/06/09');
```

Output:

```
 SELECT id,count(*)num
 FROM requestaccepted r
 JOIN LATERAL (VALUES(r.requester_id),(r.accepter_id)) s(id) ON TRUE
 group by id
 order by num desc
 Limit 1
```

Output:

| id | num |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=682de04e68030cec5391f78f3741016e)*