# Getting top 5 most associated item

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres database with a many-to-many association table that's similar to what's down below.

```
id | item_id | item_tag_id
 1     101       3
 2     102       3
 3     103       1
 4     104       2
 5     105       2
```

How can I get the top 5 most associated `item_tag_id`?

Comment: This is unclear. What does most-associated mean? Highest number of tags? Most-used tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, group by item and order by the count of rows (= count of items in a proper many-to-many design):

```sql
SELECT item_id, count(*)
FROM   assoc_tbl
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 2 DESC
LIMIT  5;
```

There is a remaining corner-case: how to break ties for the top 5? Either define criteria (resulting in more `ORDER BY` expressions), or consider `WITH TIES`. See:

- [Get top row(s) with highest value, with ties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63178114/get-top-rows-with-highest-value-with-ties/63184287#63184287)
- [Can I do a max(count(*)) in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436820/can-i-do-a-maxcount-in-sql/37780458#37780458)