# MAX Function in Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, subquery

The situation:
I have a Borrower table with columns for `ClientId` and `BorrowDate`.
I have a sub-query that finds the borrow dates grouped by `ClientId` for the year '2016' and the outer query finds the client who borrowed most.

The problem:
I am able to return the `MAX` of the `COUNT` grouped by `ClientId` of books borrowed, but when I query to also return the `ClientId` as well as the `MAX` function I get an error that says:

> The multi-part identifier "Borrower.ClientId" could not be bound.

```sql
SELECT MAX(BorrowTimes) AS MostBorrowed
FROM (SELECT Borrower.ClientId, COUNT(Borrower.BorrowDate) AS BorrowTimes
      FROM Borrower
      WHERE Borrower.BorrowDate LIKE '2016%'
      GROUP BY Borrower.ClientId
    )AS SubBorrowed;
```

How can I change the query to also return the `ClientId` of the individual associated with the MAX function?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Not tested as yet, but will do.  Been a long day, so may not have grapsed the request 100% :) `select top 1 * from
(
SELECT Borrower.ClientId, COUNT(Borrower.BorrowDate) over (partition by borrower.clientid) AS BorrowTimes
FROM Borrower
WHERE Borrower.BorrowDate LIKE '2016%'
) as q
order by q.BorrowTimes desc`

Comment: `WHERE Borrower.BorrowDate LIKE '2016%'` is not sargeable, you should use `WHERE Borrower.BorrowDate >= '20160101' AND Borrower.BorrowDate < '20170101'`

Comment: Check this question. It will solve your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436820/can-i-do-a-maxcount-in-sql#:~:text=To%20get%20one%20row%20with,John%20Travolta'%20GROUP%20BY%20c.

Comment: Learn to ask smart questions. A question about querying data from a database should include a script that contains DDL and sample data in the form of insert statements. Guessing about how you defined "BorrowDate" shouldn't be required. Do you understand how `BorrowDate LIKE '2016%` is interpreted and the comment about it? These are important things to learn and understand to write effective, efficient SQL that is resistant to errors. Lastly, have you considered that a person might borrow multiple copies of the same book on the same date? It is unusual but also possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do without an outer top 1 nesting, just ensure you have your order by

```
SELECT TOP 1
      b.ClientId, 
      COUNT(*) AS BorrowTimes
   FROM 
      Borrower b
   WHERE 
      b.BorrowDate LIKE '2016%'
   GROUP BY 
      b.ClientId
   order by
      COUNT(*) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query. It will solve the issue.

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    COUNT(BorrowDate) MostBorrowed
FROM Borrower
WHERE BorrowDate LIKE '2016%'
GROUP BY ClientId
ORDER BY BorrowTimes DESC
```