# Calculate number of rows affected by batch query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

First of all, yes I've read documentation for DO statement :)
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-do.html

So my question:

I need to execute some dynamic block of code that contains UPDATE statements and calculate the number of all affected rows. I'm using `Ado.Net` provider.

In Oracle the solution would have 4 steps:

1. add InputOutput parameter "N" to command
2. add **BEGIN ... END;** to command
3. add **:N := :N + sql%rowcount** after each statement.
4. It's done! We can read N parameter from command, after execute it.

How can I do it with PostgreSQL? I'm using npgsql provider but can migrate to devard if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is quite simple. In Oracle I need to use variables to calculate the sum of updated rows because `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` returns only the count of rows affected by the last UPDATE in the batch.

However, `npgsql` returns the sum of all rows updated by all UPDATE queries. So I only need to call `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` and get the result without any variables. Much easier than with Oracle.

Answer (score 9):

`DO` statement blocks are good to execute dynamic SQL. They are no good to return values. Use a [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html) [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) for that.

The key statement you need is:

```
GET DIAGNOSTICS integer_var = ROW_COUNT;
```

[Details in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS)

Example code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_upd_some()
  RETURNS integer AS
$func$
DECLARE
   ct int;
   i  int;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'UPDATE tbl1 ...';       -- something dynamic here
   GET DIAGNOSTICS ct = ROW_COUNT;  -- initialize with 1st count

   UPDATE tbl2 ...;                 -- nothing dynamic here 
   GET DIAGNOSTICS i = ROW_COUNT;
   ct := ct + i;                    -- add up

   RETURN ct;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_upd_some();
```