# Get the distinct sum of a joined table column

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, duplicates, window-functions

I have a problem here, and I'm hoping there is an easy solution. I'll try to make this as simple as possible:

- A ticket belongs to an attendee
- Example:

```
select * from tickets JOIN attendees ON attendee.id = tickets.attendee_id
```

- An attendee has a decimal column called "revenue"

That said, I need to run a query that will return a variety of information about the tickets, including the total revenue. The problem is that if 2 tickets belong to the same attendee, it counts their revenue twice. How can I sum the attendee revenue only once?

**I don't want to use subqueries as my ORM makes this difficult. Plus a sub query solution doesn't scale if I want to do this for multiple columns.**

Here's what I have:

- 1 attendees with a revenue of 100
- 2 tickets that both belong to that attendee

```
Select count(tickets.*) as tickets_count
     , sum(attendees.revenue) as atendees_revenue
from tickets LEFT OUTER JOIN attendees ON attendees.id = tickets.attendee_id;
```

=> This tells me that `attendees_revenue` is 200. I want it to be 100. Since there is one attendee in the database with an existing_revenue of 100. I do NOT want the attendee to be double counted.

Please let me know if this is possible.

Comment: With this kind of question it is extremely helpful if you provide a schema and sample data, preferably as an SQLFiddle - see http://sqlfiddle.com/ . That allows people writing answers to easily test with *your* schema and to make sure their queries work correctly without first having to create their own dummy data. Also: You've tagged this `SQL`, not `my-orm`. If you want SQL queries the ORM shouldn't matter; if you don't want SQL we need to know what your ORM is.

Comment: Please also show your existing subquery solution (preferably running on the SQLFiddle example you create) so we can see what the result you've trying to achieve is. The `explain analyze` of it might be informative; paste that to http://explain.depesz.com/ and link back to it here.

Comment: I think you explained the problem well, if you don't mind, try testing the following SQL against your data set: SELECT COUNT (tickets.*) AS tickets_count,
       SUM (DISTINCT attendees.revenue) AS atendees_revenue
  FROM     tickets
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
           attendees
       ON attendees.id = tickets.attendee_id

Comment: @RobertoNavarro Indeed, it's well explained (+1), and that's appreciated. I'm just being greedy and suggesting what'd be *ideal*.

Comment: @RobertoNavarro: I disagree. A table definition and some sample data is the minimum that can be expected from somebody who asks for help.

Comment: As for `A sub query solution doesn't scale if I want to do this for multiple columns.` Depending on what "do this for multiple columns" is supposed to mean, I would probably challenge this as unfounded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the result **without subquery**, you have to resort to advanced window function trickery:

```
SELECT sum(count(*))       OVER () AS tickets_count
     , sum(min(a.revenue)) OVER () AS atendees_revenue
FROM   tickets   t
JOIN   attendees a ON a.id = t.attendee_id
GROUP  BY t.attendee_id
LIMIT  1;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/161c0/4)

#### How does it work?

The key to understanding this is the **sequence of events** in the query:

*aggregate functions -> window functions -> DISTINCT -> LIMIT*

More details:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied/8242764#8242764)

Step by step:

1. I `GROUP BY t.attendee_id` - which you would normally do in a subquery.
2. Then I sum over the counts to get the total count of tickets. Not very efficient, but forced by your requirement. The aggregate function `count(*)` is wrapped in the window function `sum( ... ) OVER ()` to arrive at the not-so-common expression: `sum(count(*)) OVER ()`.

   And sum the minimum revenue per attendee to get the sum without duplicates.

   You could also use `max()` or `avg()` instead of `min()` to the same effect as `revenue` is guaranteed to be the same for every row per attendee.

   This could be simpler if `DISTINCT` was allowed in window functions, but PostgreSQL has not (yet) implemented this feature. [Per documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS):

   > Aggregate window functions, unlike normal aggregate functions, do not
   >   allow `DISTINCT` or `ORDER BY` to be used within the function argument list.
3. Final step is to get a single row. This could be done with `DISTINCT` (SQL standard) since all rows are the same. `LIMIT 1` will be faster, though. Or the SQL-standard form `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY`.

Answer (score 3):

What about a simple division:

```
 Select count(tickets.*) as tickets_count
 , sum(attendees.revenue) / count(attendees.id) as atendees_revenue
 from tickets LEFT OUTER JOIN attendees ON attendees.id = 
 tickets.attendee_id;
```

This should handle duplicates, triplicates, etcetera.

Answer (score -2):

Previous answer is nearly correct. You just need to make distinct work well in case identical revenues. You can fix this really simple if your id has numeric type:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS ticketsCount,
  SUM(DISTINCT attendees.id + attendees.revenue) - SUM(DISTINCT attendees.id) AS revenueSum
FROM
  tickets
LEFT JOIN attendees ON
  attendees.id = tickets.attendee_id
```

Comment: Quite late to the party, but this won't work either. An attendee with id `6` and revenue `4` will not be distinct from the attendee with id `4` and revenue `6`. So in this case the result (`10 - 10 = 0`) won't match the expected result (`10`).

Answer (score -3):

You were actually pretty close, there's many way to do this and if I understand your question correctly this should do it :

```
SELECT
   COUNT(*) AS ticketsCount,
   SUM(DISTINCT attendees.revenue) AS revenueSum
FROM
   tickets
   LEFT JOIN attendees ON
      attendees.id = tickets.attendee_id
```

Comment: This is incorrect, just like the deleted answer by @Mahmoud. It would not consider identical revenues from two *different* attendees `DISTINCT` and report a smaller `revenueSum` than is correct.

Comment: do NOT do this, it will sum all revenues that aren't the same, so if you have a revenue that is `50` and another that's also `50` it will only add the first one.