# Get rows with maximum count

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I need to perform a query to get the candies that are most liked by kids and here's what I've got:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as counts,candies.name
FROM candies 
INNER JOIN kid_candy ON kid_candy.candy_id = candies.id
INNER JOIN kids ON kids.id = kid_candy.kid_id
GROUP BY candies.name
```

which would return:

```
counts  | name
--------+---------
  3     | snowbear
  3     | whiterabbit
  2     | lollipop
```

All I want to see would be just

```
counts  | name
--------+---------
  3     | snowbear
  3     | whiterabbit
```

So what should my query be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming **a classical n:m relationship** between kids and candies like detailed here:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

You should provide such details in your question.

```
SELECT c.id, kc.counts, c.name
FROM  (
   SELECT candy_id AS id, count(*) AS counts
        , rank() OVER (ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS rnk
   FROM   kid_candy
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) kc
JOIN   candies c USING (id)
WHERE  kc.rnk = 1;
```

This should be considerably faster than a query with two CTEs and needless joins.

#### Major points

- It is potentially wrong (and more expensive) to group by `candies.name`. The name might not be unique. Use the primary key column for that, which is probably `candies.id`
- Assuming referential integrity we do not need to join to the table `kids` at all.
- Since we need to inspect the whole table, it is faster to *aggregate first* and *join* to candies to get the `name` *later*.
- You can run a window function over an aggregate function:

  - [Get the distinct sum of a joined table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169367/get-the-distinct-sum-of-a-joined-table-column/13169627#13169627)

Answer (score 3):

So, first lets get the counts per candy name (`tmp_table`), then get the max count of all candies (`max_cnt`) and finally put it all together and get the candies from `tmp_table` which have a count equal to `max(counts)` from `max_cnt` table...

```
 with tmp_table AS (
    select COUNT(*) as counts,candies.name as c_name
    from candies 
    INNER JOIN kid_candy ON kid_candy.candy_id = candies.id
    INNER JOIN kids ON kids.id = kid_candy.kid_id
    GROUP BY candies.name        
 ), 
 max_cnt AS (
    SELECT max(counts) as max_count from tmp_table
 )
 SELECT counts, c_name as candies
 FROM tmp_table 
 JOIN max_cnt on max_count = counts
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS Counts,candies.name FROM candies 
     INNER JOIN kid_candy ON kid_candy.candy_id = candies.id
     INNER JOIN kids ON kids.id = kid_candy.kid_id
   GROUP BY candies.name
 ) T1 JOIN
SELECT MAX(counts) MaxCount FROM
(
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS Counts,candies.name FROM candies 
      INNER JOIN kid_candy ON kid_candy.candy_id = candies.id
      INNER JOIN kids ON kids.id = kid_candy.kid_id
   GROUP BY candies.name
) T1 ON T1.counts =T2.MaxCount
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a sub select

```
Select max(counts) 
    (select COUNT(*) as counts,candies.name from candies 
INNER JOIN kid_candy ON kid_candy.candy_id = candies.id
INNER JOIN kids ON kids.id = kid_candy.kid_id
GROUP BY candies.name)
```

Comment: This would just get a the maximum count, not the desired result, but the syntax is wrong: missing `FROM` clause, missing table alias.