# SQL - getting max value

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count, aggregate-functions

The below query gives me results for count greater than 70.

```
SELECT books.name, COUNT(library.staff)
FROM (library INNER JOIN books
ON library.staff = books.id)
GROUP BY library.staff,books.id
HAVING COUNT(library.staff) > 70;
```

How do I modify my query to get the result with the *maximum* count?

Comment: Can we assume that `books.id` is the primary key of `books`? Table definitions (what you get with `\d books` in psql) and your version of Postgres would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT b.name, COUNT(l.staff) as cnt
FROM library l INNER JOIN
     books b
     ON l.staff = b.id
GROUP BY l.staff, b.name
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

I find it strange that you are grouping by two columns, but only one is in the `select`.  However, if the query is working, then it is just looking for duplicates.

Comment: Is there any other alternative to using LIMIT 1? I mean instead of using LIMIT is there any other way of getting the same result?

Comment: @lel . . . There are lots of ways.  This is likely to have the good performance relative to the others and is probably the simplest to code.

Comment: can you please tell me an other way. I am trying to get the output without having to use limit unless its absolute necessary.

Comment: @lel . . . What do you want to avoid `limit`?  It is a very reasonable approach.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
SELECT books.name, COUNT(library.staff)
FROM (library INNER JOIN books
ON library.staff = books.id)
GROUP BY library.staff,books.id
HAVING COUNT(library.staff) = (select max(library.staff) from library);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can us ORDER BY() DESC and LIMIT 1

```
SELECT books.name, COUNT(library.staff)
FROM (library INNER JOIN books
ON library.staff = books.id)
GROUP BY library.staff,books.id
ORDER BY COUNT(library.staff) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Really?

You join on `library.staff = books.id`. That's a surprising naming convention. The ID of a book equals the "staff" of a library? You should provide table definitions and some explanation with that ...

For the purpose of this answer, let's assume this is correct.

#### Audited query

Besides using table aliases for better readability, you can simplify in several places:

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, count(*) AS ct
FROM   library l
JOIN   books b ON b.id = l.staff 
GROUP  BY b.id  -- l.staff -- redundant
HAVING count(*) > 70;
```

- Since you are joining on `b.id = l.staff`, `l.staff` is guaranteed to be `NOT NULL`, so use [`count(*)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE), which is a bit faster while doing the same (separate implementation of count which only counts rows without looking at columns).
- `GROUP  BY b.id` does the same without `l.staff` in this case.
- But since you are grouping by `b.id`, not by `b.name`, there might be duplicate names we can only tell apart by adding `id` to the result - unless `name` is unique, which you did not specify.

#### Faster query

Assuming that `books.id` is the primary key which seems reasonable:

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, l.ct
FROM   books b 
JOIN  (
   SELECT staff AS id, count(*) AS ct 
   FROM   library 
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) l USING (id)
HAVING count(*) > 70;
```

Reading the whole table or most of it, it is typically substantially faster to aggregate first, and then join.

- [Aggregate a single column in query with many columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018237/aggregate-a-single-column-in-query-with-many-columns/16023336#16023336)

Test with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html).

### Answer

To get result(s) with maximum count, `ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1` like other answers provided is typically the fastest option - to get ***one* winner**.

To get ***all* winners**:

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, l.ct
FROM   books b 
JOIN  (
   SELECT staff AS id, count(*) AS ct
        , rank() OVER (ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS rnk
   FROM   library 
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) l USING (id)
WHERE  l.rnk = 1;
```

Using the [window function `rank()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) here (not `row_number()`).
Note that you can combine aggregate functions and window functions in a single `SELECT`:

- [Get the distinct sum of a joined table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169367/get-the-distinct-sum-of-a-joined-table-column/13169627#13169627)