# Find most occurring Col3 for every pair of Col1 and Col2

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, amazon-redshift

Given a table `myTable` with 4 columns, say `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3` and `Col4`:

```
A X 5 B
A Y 5 C
A X 7 D
A Y 3 E 
A X 7 F
```

I need to find most occurring `col3` for each pair `(col1, col2)`.

So result for this example will be:

```
A X 7   D/F  -- D or F
A Y 5/3 C/E  -- It can be 5 and C or 3 and E
```

So I wrote a query something like this :

```
select Col1,Col2,Col3 
from myTable M 
group by Col1,Col2,Col3 
having Col3 =
     (select Col3 
      from myTable N 
      where M.Col1=N.col1 
      group by Col3 
      order by Col3 desc limit 1);
```

But the query does not give the desired result.
Also I have no idea how to get `Col4` as am making group by clause, and I don't want to make group by according to `Col4`.

For each `(Col1, Col2)` pair I want single `Col4` that goes along with the maximum occurring `Col3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need a single subquery with **`DISTINCT ON`**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (col1, col2)
       col1, col2, col3, min(col4) As col4
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY col1, col2, col3
ORDER  BY col1, col2, count(*) DESC, col3;
```

This way you get a ***single*** row per `(col1, col2)` with the ***most common*** `col3` (the samllest value if multiple tie for "most common") an the ***smallest*** `col4` to go along with that `col3`.

---

Similarly, to get *all* qualifying `col3` you can use the [window function **`rank()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) in a subquery, which is also executed *after* the aggregation:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4_list
FROM  (
   SELECT col1, col2, col3, count(*) AS ct, string_agg(col4, '/') AS col4_list
        , rank() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS rnk
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY col1, col2, col3
   ) sub
WHERE  rnk = 1
ORDER  BY col1, col2, col3;
```

This works, because you can run window functions *over* aggregate functions.
Cast to `text` if the data type is not a [character type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html).

---

Or, all qualifying `col3` per `(col1, col2)` in a list, plus all matching `col4` in a second list:

```
SELECT col1, col2
     , string_agg(col3::text, '/') AS col3_list  -- cast if necessary
     , string_agg(col4_list,  '/') AS col4_list
FROM  (
   SELECT col1, col2, col3, count(*) AS ct, string_agg(col4, '/') AS col4_list
        , rank() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS rnk
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY col1, col2, col3
   ) sub
WHERE  rnk = 1
GROUP  BY col1, col2
ORDER  BY col1, col2, col3_list;
```

Related answers with more explanation:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied-in-php-postgresql/8242764#8242764)
- [Get the distinct sum of a joined table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169367/get-the-distinct-sum-of-a-joined-table-column/13169627#13169627)

#### Solution for Amazon Redshift

[`row_number()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_ROW_NUMBER.html) is available, so this should work:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM  (
   SELECT col1, col2, col3, min(col4) AS col4
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2
                             ORDER BY count(*) DESC, col3) AS rn
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY col1, col2, col3
   ) sub
WHERE  rn = 1
ORDER  BY col1, col2;
```

Or if window functions over aggregate functions are not allowed, use another subquery

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM  (
   SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2
                                ORDER BY ct DESC, col3) AS rn
   FROM (
      SELECT col1, col2, col3, min(col4) AS col4, COUNT(*) AS ct
      FROM   tbl
      GROUP  BY col1, col2, col3
      ) sub1
   ) sub2
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

This picks the smallest `col3` if more than one tie for the maximum count. And the smallest `col4` for the respective `col3`.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e363d/19) demonstrating all in Postgres 9.3.

Comment: I want any one of the two, in Col4 and not both. I dont want any array list. Just see, I had put OR and not AND

Comment: If you really don't care which col4, `min(col4)` or `max(col4)` are easy substitutes for the string_agg.

Comment: @GitCoder: Or you can combine the aggregate with `DISTINCT ON`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f4b19/1 . I want that instead of two rows for (A,Y) pair, only single row should be there

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f4b19/1 . I want that instead of two rows for (A,Y) pair, only single row should be there

Comment: @GitCoder: You may have missed my update from yesterday. The solution is already there (first query). I updated the fiddle now, too.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter DISTINCT ON is not supported with my PSQL. So whats way out ?

Comment: @GitCoder: What is "your PSQL" exactly? (This kind of information should be among the first things in your question.)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Amazon Redshift

Comment: @GitCoder: Next time please declare your actual RDBMS up front. It's a frustrating process to waste time until you come forward.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is with the `row_number()` window function on top of the aggregate query:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM   (SELECT col1, col2, col3, 
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY cnt DESC) AS rn
        FROM (SELECT   col1, col2, col3, COUNT(*) AS cnt
              FROM     mytable
              GROUP BY col1, col2, col3) t
       ) q
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PARTITION"
LINE 3:         row_number (PARTITION BY comp_sku, zone_id ORDER BY ...What can be the reason ?

Comment: @GitCoder the reason is I wasn't paying attention and completely forgot the `over` clause. Edited and fixed, try now.

Comment: Suppose if we have one more column Col4, and want in result, then how to get this also. Because we dont want it in group by clause

Comment: Like for any Col1,Col2 pair any Col4 matching the criteria will work out if there are multiple options.