# PostgreSQL: get the max values from a consult

Tags: sql, postgresql, max

I need to get the max values from a list of values obtained from a query.

Basically, the problem is this:

I have 2 tables:

- Lawyer

  - id (PK)
  - surname
  - name
- Case

  - id (PK)
  - id_Client
  - date
  - id_Lawyer (FK)

And I need to get the Lawyer with the largest number of cases...(There is not problem with that) but, if exist more than one lawyer with the largest number of cases, I should list them.
Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: please show your attempt too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL equivalent for TOP n WITH TIES: LIMIT "with ties"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629953/postgresql-equivalent-for-top-n-with-ties-limit-with-ties)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT l.*, cases
FROM  (
   SELECT "id_Lawyer", count(*) AS cases, rank() OVER (ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS rnk
   FROM   "Case"
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) c
JOIN   "Lawyer" l ON l.id = c."id_Lawyer"
WHERE  c.rnk = 1;
```

Basics for the technique (like [@FuzzyTree provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33204574/postgresql-get-the-max-values-from-a-consult/33206265#comment54214186_33204574)):

- [PostgreSQL equivalent for TOP n WITH TIES: LIMIT "with ties"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629953/postgresql-equivalent-for-top-n-with-ties-limit-with-ties)

You only need a single subquery level since you can run window functions over aggregate functions:

- [Get the distinct sum of a joined table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169367/get-the-distinct-sum-of-a-joined-table-column/13169627#13169627)
- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied-in-php-postgresql/8242764#8242764)

Aside: It's better to use legal, lower case, unquoted identifiers in Postgres. Never use a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) like `Case`, that can lead to very confusing errors.