# Pivot table without crosstab/tablefunc

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, crosstab, aggregate-filter

I have a table like this

**INPUT**

```
id    author    size    file_ext
--------------------------------
1     a         13661   python
1     a         13513   cpp
1     a         1211    non-code
2     b         1019    python
2     b         6881    cpp
2     b         1525    python
2     b         1208    non-code
3     c         1039    python 
3     c         1299    cpp
```

I want to be able to pivot this table in the following manner

**OUTPUT**

```
id    author    size    python    cpp    non-code
-------------------------------------------------
1     a         13661   1         0      0
1     a         13513   0         1      0
1     a         1211    0         0      1 
2     b         1019    1         0      0
2     b         6881    0         1      0
2     b         1525    1         0      0
2     b         1208    0         0      1
3     c         1039    1         0      0
3     c         1299    0         1      0
```

All the articles that I can find online pivot tables based on a second column. My ultimate goal is to get one records per ID.

**FINAL OUTPUT**

```
id    author    size    python    cpp    non-code
-------------------------------------------------
1     a         28385   1         1      1
2     b         10633   2         1      1
3     c         2338    1         1      0
```

Here the values of the size, python, cpp, non-code columns are aggregated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select 
  id, author,
  sum(size) size,
  sum((file_ext = 'python')::int) python,
  sum((file_ext = 'cpp')::int) cpp,
  sum((file_ext = 'non-code')::int) "non-code"
from tablename
group by id, author
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=12eb2f916b2b1f200bc1160bbf1b2f02).
Results:

```
> id | author |  size | python | cpp | non-code
> -: | :----- | ----: | -----: | --: | -------:
>  1 | a      | 28385 |      1 |   1 |        1
>  2 | b      | 10633 |      2 |   1 |        1
>  3 | c      |  2338 |      1 |   1 |        0
```

Comment: You have all the possible file extensions hard coded into the query. Is there a way to do it if you don't know all the possible file extensions?

Comment: @djsosofresh Postgresql does not support (at the moment as far as I know) dynamic pivoting. Check the link in Mohamad's answer for an extension function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks like the crosstab function mentioned in Mohomad's answer also requires the names and types of the output columns to be defined.

Answer (score 3):

While you want to avoid the `crosstab()` function, use the aggregate `FILTER` clause for best performance and clearest code:

```
SELECT id, author
     , sum(size) AS size
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE file_ext = 'python')   AS python
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE file_ext = 'cpp')      AS cpp
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE file_ext = 'non-code') AS "non-code"
FROM   tablename
GROUP  BY id, author;
```

That's the fastest way with just aggregate functions. See:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27572/3684)
- [How can I simplify this game statistics query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)

For absolute best performance, `crosstab()` is typically faster - even though more verbose in this case:

```
SELECT id, author, size
     , COALESCE(python    , 0) AS python
     , COALESCE(cpp       , 0) AS cpp
     , COALESCE("non-code", 0) AS "non-code"
FROM   crosstab(
$$
SELECT id, author
     , sum(sum(size)) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS size
     , file_ext
     , count(*) AS ct
FROM   tablename
GROUP  BY id, author, file_ext
ORDER  BY id, author, file_ext
$$
, $$VALUES ('python'), ('cpp'), ('non-code')$$
) AS (id int, author text, size numeric
    , python int, cpp int, "non-code" int);
```

Same result.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c97893a3dc6ce12abb4f43262a6ae32c)* - *with intermediary steps*.

Detailed explanation:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)
- [Pivot on Multiple Columns using Tablefunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415446/pivot-on-multiple-columns-using-tablefunc/15421607#15421607)

For the window function over the aggregate function (`sum(sum(size)) OVER (...)`), see:

- [Get the distinct sum of a joined table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169367/get-the-distinct-sum-of-a-joined-table-column/13169627#13169627)

Note a subtle difference if there should be more than one `author` for the same `id`: while the first query returns multiple rows in this case, the `crosstab()` variant just picks the first author.

Comment: Most of the time when I have a question about Postgresql I stumble upon one of your high quality answers. This is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the PostgreSQL crosstab function extension called **tablefunc**. I advise you to take a look at this link (the example given, there, is very similar to the result you want):https://vertabelo.com/blog/creating-pivot-tables-in-postgresql-using-the-crosstab-function/