# How to group multiple rows in to a single row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've used crosstab function and ended up with a table that has a single column value on each row.

```
|  ID  |  c1  |  c2  |  c3  |
-----------------------------
|  1   |      |  1   |      |
|  1   |  4   |      |      |
|  1   |      |      |  12  |
|  15  |  2   |      |      |
|  15  |      |      |  3   |
```

and want to change it so that the ID is distinct and all values are on the same row:

```
|  ID  |  c1  |  c2  |  c3  |
-----------------------------
|  1   |  4   |  1   |  12  |
|  15  |  2   |      |  3   |
```

What is the best way to do this? I could use an aggregate function like `SUM` and `GROUP BY id` but that makes pointless calculations that aren't required.

Comment: use MAX if the rest is NULL

Comment: You forgot to provide the statement you used. Plus necessary details to reproduce.

Comment: `SELECT id, max(c1),max(c2),max(c3) FROM t GROUP BY id`

Comment: @JimJones: We wouldn't need `crosstab()` for the simple aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, with `crosstab()` from the additional module `tablefunc`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
   'SELECT id, key, value
    FROM   tbl
    ORDER  BY 1' -- !

  , $$VALUES ('c1'), ('c2'), ('c3')$$
   ) AS ct ("ID" text, c1 int, c2 int, c3 int);
```

See (with detailed explanation):

- [Pivot on Multiple Columns using Tablefunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415446/pivot-on-multiple-columns-using-tablefunc/15421607#15421607)

Or with pure SQL:

```sql
SELECT id
     , min(value) FILTER (WHERE key = 'c1') AS c1
     , min(value) FILTER (WHERE key = 'c2') AS c2
     , min(value) FILTER (WHERE key = 'c3') AS c3
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Optionally add `WHERE key = ANY('{c1,c2,c3}')` to each query.
Adapt to your actual, undisclosed data types and requirements.

Each has its pros and cons. See:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)
- [Pivot table without crosstab/tablefunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60120978/pivot-table-without-crosstab-tablefunc/60123192#60123192)
- [Build a select query that includes aggregated values from a different table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/273958/3684)