# SQLAlchemy add columns to query() on mapped class

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, pagination, sqlalchemy

I'm wanting to do pagination, I'm using PostgreSQL. To avoid doing the query twice, I'm using the feature described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8242764

How can I add the `full_count` column to the list of columns fetched in my query. I can use `query.add_columns`, but that column is not accessible after calling `query.all()`

Is this possible in SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you provide the original code for the query you want to augment? Are you using SQLAlchemy core or declarative ORM? For the latter it will look like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

items = session.query(Model, func.count().over().label('full_count')).all()
obj = items[0].Model
count = items[0].full_count
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I was doing before, but it definitely wasn't what you've suggested. Your solution was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Is there a way to do this where the 'full_count' field gets placed directly on the Model? So items[0] would return the same as items[0].Model in your example above, except that items[0].full_count would contain the result of the func.count()?

Comment: You may be able to get what you want using [query-time SQL expressions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#query-time-sql-expressions-as-mapped-attributes). [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60908024/1749551).