# Flask sqlalchemy add column during query without tuple result

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am working on a flask project and I am stuck on an issue where I am trying to add a case statement to a query as a column.

I have tried lots of potential solutions and the closest I have found so far is `add_columns()` the problem is that this makes the query return a tuple with the object of the model I queried and result from the case statement, what I want is just the model object that has the result of the case in it.

here is some simplified code that shows my issue

```py
from flask import Flask
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import case
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///database.db"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Image(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'images'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = db.Column(db.Text)
    model_id = db.Column(db.Integer)


db.create_all()


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    image_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    image_weights = [0.1, 0.4, 0.23232, 0.21, 0.001]
    print(list(zip(image_ids, image_weights)))

    case_statement = case(
        [(uid == Image.id, weight) for uid, weight in zip(image_ids, image_weights)]
    )
    results = db.session.query(Image).add_columns(case_statement.label("weight")).filter(
        Image.id.in_(image_ids)).order_by("weight")
    print(results)
    print(results.all())
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

the output of `print(results.statement.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))` is

```sql
SELECT images.id,
       images.url,
       images.model_id,
       CASE WHEN (images.id = 1) THEN 0.1 WHEN (images.id = 2) THEN 0.4 WHEN (images.id = 3) THEN 0.23232 WHEN (images.id = 4) THEN 0.21 WHEN (images.id = 5) THEN 0.001 END AS weight
  FROM images
 WHERE images.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
 ORDER BY weight;
```

the output of `print(results.all())`

```py
[(<Image 5>, 0.001), (<Image 1>, 0.1), (<Image 4>, 0.21), (<Image 3>, 0.23232), (<Image 2>, 0.4)]
```

the result I am looking for is

```py
[<Image 5>, <Image 1>, <Image 4>, <Image 3>, <Image 2>]
```

One easy solution to this is to just go over each item in the list of results and use setattr to set a attribute weight of the image object to the second item in the tuple but I can't do this as I want to make a function that returns a query object with the filters applied not a list of objects

Comment: add_columns will always add a new column. Check out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381644/how-to-order-data-in-sqlalchemy-by-list). Maybe it helps. Nice question +1

Comment: @Sikan thanks for the help. I had a look at that post and even though it did not give me an answer directly it did still help, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching through the sqlalchemy documentation I found [Query-time SQL expressions as mapped attributes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#query-time-sql-expressions-as-mapped-attributes)

This dose exactly what I want It lets me set a mapped attribute weight that is the result of a case statement.

### changes I made to my code

```
class Image(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'images'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = db.Column(db.Text)
    model_id = db.Column(db.Integer)

    weight = db.query_expression()
```

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    image_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    image_weights = [0.1, 0.4, 0.23232, 0.21, 0.001]

    case_statement = case([(uid == Image.id, weight) for uid, weight in zip(image_ids, image_weights)]).label("weight")
    results = db.session.query(Image).filter(Image.id.in_(image_ids)).options(
        db.with_expression(Image.weight, case_statement)).order_by(case_statement)
    print(results.statement.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))
    for result in results:
        print(result, result.weight)
    return 'Hello World!'
```

results.all() now returns

```
[<Image 5>, <Image 1>, <Image 4>, <Image 3>, <Image 2>]
```

and each item in this list now as an attribute called weight

If there is a better way of doing this please let me know thanks