# Find rows with duplicate values in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a table `author_data`:

```
 author_id | author_name
 ----------+----------------
 9         | ernest jordan
 14        | k moribe
 15        | ernest jordan
 25        | william h nailon 
 79        | howard jason
 36        | k moribe
```

Now I need the result as:

```
 author_id | author_name                                                  
 ----------+----------------
 9         | ernest jordan
 15        | ernest jordan     
 14        | k moribe 
 36        | k moribe
```

That is, I need the `author_id` for the names having duplicate appearances. I have tried this statement:

```
select author_id,count(author_name)
from author_data
group by author_name
having count(author_name)>1
```

But it's not working. How can I get this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) in a subquery:

```
SELECT author_id, author_name  -- omit the name here if you just need ids
FROM (
   SELECT author_id, author_name
        , count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY author_name) AS ct
   FROM   author_data
   ) sub
WHERE  ct > 1;
```

You will recognize the basic aggregate function `count()`. It can be turned into a window function by appending an `OVER` clause - just like any other aggregate function.

This way it counts rows *per partition*. Voilá.

It has to be done in a subquery because the result cannot be referenced in the `WHERE` clause in the same `SELECT` (happens *after* `WHERE`). See:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied/8242764#8242764)

In older versions without window functions (v.8.3 or older) - or generally - this alternative performs pretty fast:

```
SELECT author_id, author_name  -- omit name, if you just need ids
FROM   author_data a
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM author_data a2
   WHERE  a2.author_name = a.author_name
   AND    a2.author_id <> a.author_id
   );
```

If you are concerned with performance, add an index on `author_name`.

Answer (score 3):

You are half way there already. You need to just use the identified `Author_IDs` and fetch the rest of the data.

try this..

```
SELECT author_id, author_name
FROM author_data
WHERE author_id in (select author_id
        from author_data
        group by author_name
        having count(author_name)>1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could join the table onto itself, which is achievable with either of the following queries:

```
SELECT a1.author_id, a1.author_name
FROM authors a1
CROSS JOIN authors a2
  ON a1.author_id <> a2.author_id
  AND a1.author_name = a2.author_name;

-- 9 |ernest jordan
-- 15|ernest jordan
-- 14|k moribe
-- 36|k moribe

--OR

SELECT a1.author_id, a1.author_name
FROM authors a1
INNER JOIN authors a2
  WHERE a1.author_id <> a2.author_id
  AND a1.author_name = a2.author_name;

-- 9 |ernest jordan
-- 15|ernest jordan
-- 14|k moribe
-- 36|k moribe
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the answer you mentioned in the question, the whole query will fetch for you but if you just want the duplicate one, you can use the `inner query`.  You can use windows functions, Row, Dense rank also, to get your answers

```
select a.author_id, 
a.author_name 
from authors a JOIN
   (
    select author_name
    from authors
    group by author_name
    having count(author_name) >1
   ) as temp
on a.author_name = temp.author_name
```