# Cumulative count of duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

For a table looking like

```
ID    | Value
-------------
1     | 2
2     | 10
3     | 3
4     | 2
5     | 0
6     | 3
7     | 3
```

I would like to calculate the number of IDs with a higher `Value`, for each `Value` that appears in the table, i.e.

```
Value | Position
----------------
10    | 0
3     | 1
2     | 4
0     | 6
```

This equates to the offset of the `Value` in a `ORDER BY Value` ordering.

I have considered doing this by calculating the number of duplicates with something like

```
SELECT Value, count(*) AS ct FROM table GROUP BY Value";
```

And then cumulating the result, but I guess that is not the optimal way to do it (nor have I managed to combine the commands accordingly)

How would one go about calculating this efficiently (for several dozens of thousands of rows)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a perfect opportunity for the [window function **`rank()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) (not the related `dense_rank()`):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (value)
       value, rank() OVER (ORDER BY value DESC) - 1 AS position
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY value DESC;
```

`rank()` starts with 1, while your count starts with 0, so subtract 1.

Adding a `DISTINCT` step (`DISTINCT ON` is slightly cheaper here) to remove duplicate rows (*after* computing counting ranks). `DISTINCT` is applied after window functions. Details in this related answer:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied-in-php-postgresql/8242764#8242764)

Result exactly as requested.
An index on `value` will help performance.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3ea67/7)

Comment: Incredible. I would not have thought that command/function exists! Thank you very much. The rank() is even better for what I am attempting it turned out, so everything is great!

Answer (score 1):

You might also try this if you're not comfortable with window functions:

```
SELECT t1.value, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.id) AS position
  FROM tbl t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl t2
    ON t1.value < t2.value
 GROUP BY t1.value
```

Note the self-join.