# How do I group a collection of elements by whether or not they have consecutive values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

So given a table like the one below, I would like to grab rows where `id` has at least three consecutive years.

```
+---------+--------+
|    id   |  year  |
+------------------+
|    2    |   2003 |
|    2    |   2004 |
|    1    |   2005 |
|    2    |   2005 |
|    1    |   2007 |
|    1    |   2008 |
+---------+--------+
```

The result over here would be of course:

```
+---------+         
|   id    |         
+---------+         
|    2    |         
+---------+
```

Any input at all as to how I could go about structuring a query to do this would be great.

Comment: Do you want a SQL query statement to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works and can be fast when you have at least an index on the id-field:

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (VALUES
            (2,2003),
            (2,2004),
            (1,2005),
            (2,2005),
            (1,2007),
            (1,2008)
            ) v(id, year) 
)
SELECT  DISTINCT t1.id
FROM    t1 -- your tablename
    JOIN t1 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.year + 1 = t2.year
    JOIN t1 AS t3 ON t1.id = t3.id AND t1.year + 2 = t3.year;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JOIN` approach (*self-join*):

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM tbl t1 
JOIN tbl t2 ON t2.year = t1.year + 1
           AND t1.id = t2.id
JOIN tbl t3 ON t3.year = t1.year + 2
           AND t1.id = t3.id
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ddf2a8/3)

Answer (score 1):

#### Combination `(id, year)` is `UNIQUE`

Typically guaranteed with a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint or a unique index.

This is a general solution for any minimum number of consecutive rows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM  (
   SELECT id, year - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year) AS grp
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
GROUP  BY id, grp
HAVING count(*) > 2;  -- minimum: 3
```

This should be faster than self-joining repeatedly, because only a **single scan** on the base table is needed. Test performance with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

Related answer with detailed explanation:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35389/3684)

#### Combination `(id, year)` is not `UNIQUE`

You can *make* it unique in a first step.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM  (
   SELECT id, year - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year) AS grp
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY id, year
   ) sub
GROUP  BY id, grp
HAVING count(*) > 2;  -- minimum: 3
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5b912/1)

Or you could use the window function [`dense_rank()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) instead of `row_number()` and then `count(DISTINCT year)`, but I don't see a benefit in this approach.

Understanding the *sequence of events* in a `SELECT` query is the key:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied-in-php-postgresql/8242764#8242764)