# Get the count of rows count after GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord, relational-division

Here is the code I use in a Ruby on Rails project to find `residences` which have `amenities` with the `ids` 48, 49 and 50. They are connected with a has_many through connection.

```
id_list = [48, 49, 50]
Residence.joins(:listed_amenities).
          where(listed_amenities: {amenity_id: id_list}).
          group('residences.id').
          having("count(listed_amenities.*) = ?", id_list.size)
```

The resulting SQL:

```
SELECT "residences".*
FROM "residences"
INNER JOIN "listed_amenities" ON "listed_amenities"."residence_id" = "residences"."id"
WHERE "listed_amenities"."amenity_id" IN (48, 49, 50)
GROUP BY residences.id
HAVING count(listed_amenities.*) = 3
```

I'm interested in the number of `residences` that result from this query. Is there a way to add a `count` or something else to let the database do that calculation? I don't want to waste computing power by doing it in Ruby. Adding a `.count` method doesn't work. It results in `{528747=>3, 529004=>3, 529058=>3}`.

Comment: Do you *only* want the count of qualifying residences or the list of IDs (or even whole rows) additionally? And *always* disclose the version of Postgres in use, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your design enforces referential integrity, you don't have to join to the table `residences` for this purpose at all. Also assuming a `UNIQUE` or `PK` constraint on `(residence_id, amenity_id)` (else you need different queries!)

The best query depends on what you need *exactly*.

Using a window function, you *can* even do this in a single query level:

```
SELECT count(*) OVER () AS ct
FROM   listed_amenities
WHERE  amenity_id IN (48, 49, 50)
GROUP  BY residence_id
HAVING count(*) = 3
LIMIT  1;
```

This window function appends the total count to every row without aggregating rows. Consider the sequence of events in a `SELECT` query:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied-in-php-postgresql/8242764#8242764)

Accordingly, you could use a similar query to return all qualifying IDs (or even whole rows) and append the count to every row (redundantly):

```
SELECT residence_id, count(*) OVER () AS ct
FROM   listed_amenities
WHERE  amenity_id IN (48, 49, 50)
GROUP  BY residence_id
HAVING count(*) = 3;
```

But better use a subquery, that's ***typically much cheaper***:

```
SELECT count(*) AS ct
FROM  (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   listed_amenities
   WHERE  amenity_id IN (48, 49, 50)
   GROUP  BY residence_id 
   HAVING count(*) = 3
   ) sub;
```

You *could* return an array of IDs (as opposed to the *set* above) at the same time, for hardly any more cost:

```
SELECT array_agg(residence_id ) AS ids, count(*) AS ct
FROM  (
   SELECT residence_id 
   FROM   listed_amenities
   WHERE  amenity_id IN (48, 49, 50)
   GROUP  BY residence_id
   HAVING count(*) = 3
   ) sub;
```

There are many other variants, you would have to clarify the expected result. Like this one:

```
SELECT count(*) AS ct
FROM   listed_amenities l1
JOIN   listed_amenities l2 USING (residence_id)
JOIN   listed_amenities l3 USING (residence_id)
WHERE  l1.amenity_id = 48
AND    l2.amenity_id = 49
AND    l2.amenity_id = 50;
```

Basically it's a case of relational division. We have assembled an arsenal of techniques here:

- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879#7774879)