# Find a cheaper SQL for a complicated Rails query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

A `Country` has_many `residences` and a `Residence` has_many `listed_amenities` which are linked to `amenities`. I need to know how many `residences` which are located in the `Country` with the id 1 have the `amenities` with the ids [48, 49, 50] (they can have more but they have to have all three of them).

The following Ruby on Rails (v4.2.4) code does the trick:

```
id_list = [48, 49, 50]
Country.first.
        residences.
        where(id: Residence.
        joins(:listed_amenities).
        where(listed_amenities: {amenity_id: id_list}).
        group('residences.id').
        having("count(listed_amenities.*) = ?", id_list.size).
        pluck(:id)).
        count
```

It results in the following SQL:

```
SELECT  "countries".* 
FROM "countries"  
ORDER BY "countries"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

SELECT "residences"."id" 
FROM "residences" 
INNER JOIN "listed_amenities" 
ON "listed_amenities"."residence_id" = "residences"."id" 
WHERE "listed_amenities"."amenity_id" IN (48, 49, 50) 
GROUP BY residences.id 
HAVING count(listed_amenities.*) = 3

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM "residences" 
WHERE "residences"."country_id" = $1 
AND "residences"."id" 
IN (51, 59, 60, ...)  [["country_id", 1]]
```

Obviously that is an expensive way to solve the given problem and each table has more than 1,000,000 entries.

**How can I solve this on a PostgreSQL (9.4.4) in a better/faster way?** Is there one magic SQL line which does the trick?

Thanks to "[Get the count of rows count after GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32704765/get-the-count-of-rows-count-after-group-by)" I have the following SQL query for doing the search over all `residences` but I lack the SQL know-how to connect the `Country` to it:

```
SELECT count(*) AS ct
FROM  (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   listed_amenities
   WHERE  amenity_id IN (48, 49, 50)
   GROUP  BY residence_id 
   HAVING count(*) = 3
   ) sub;
```

### The Ruby on Rails setup:

```
rails g scaffold Country name
rails g scaffold Residence country:references name:string
rails g scaffold Amenity name:string
rails g scaffold ListedAmenity residence:references amenity:references
```

**app/models/country.rb**

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :residences
end
```

**app/models/residences.rb**

```
class Residence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country

  has_many :listed_amenities
  has_many :amenities, through: :listed_amenities
end
```

**app/models/amenities.rb**

```
class Residence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country

  has_many :listed_amenities
  has_many :amenities, through: :listed_amenities
end
```

**app/models/listed_amenities.rb**

```
class ListedAmenity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :residence
  belongs_to :amenity
end
```

Comment: Your code results in 3 queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could probably simplify this to:

```
Residence.
    joins(:listed_amenities, :country).
    where(listed_amenities: {amenity_id: id_list}).
    where(countries: {id: 1}).
    group('residences.id').
    having("count(listed_amenities.*) = ?", id_list.size)
```

For the count, try adding:

```
    count.count
```

Comment: That results in the list of `residences` but I need the count. Adding the `.count` method to it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm going to need a hint as to the error message ;)

Comment: `... 529042=>3, 529050=>3, 529062=>3, 529064=>3, 529067=>3, 529070=>3, 529071=>3, 529077=>3, 529082=>3, 530547=>3}`