# Find the longest streak of perfect scores per player

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a the following result from a `SELECT` query with `ORDER BY player_id ASC, time ASC` in PostgreSQL database:

```
player_id  points  time

395        0       2018-06-01 17:55:23.982413-04
395        100     2018-06-30 11:05:21.8679-04
395        0       2018-07-15 21:56:25.420837-04
395        100     2018-07-28 19:47:13.84652-04
395        0       2018-11-27 17:09:59.384-05
395        100     2018-12-02 08:56:06.83033-05
399        0       2018-05-15 15:28:22.782945-04
399        100     2018-06-10 12:11:18.041521-04
454        0       2018-07-10 18:53:24.236363-04
675        0       2018-08-07 20:59:15.510936-04
696        0       2018-08-07 19:09:07.126876-04
756        100     2018-08-15 08:21:11.300871-04
756        100     2018-08-15 16:43:08.698862-04
756        0       2018-08-15 17:22:49.755721-04
756        100     2018-10-07 15:30:49.27374-04
756        0       2018-10-07 15:35:00.975252-04
756        0       2018-11-27 19:04:06.456982-05
756        100     2018-12-02 19:24:20.880022-05
756        100     2018-12-04 19:57:48.961111-05
```

I'm trying to find each player's longest streak where `points = 100`, with the tiebreaker being whichever streak began most recently. I also need to determine the time at which that player's longest streak began. The expected result would be:

```
player_id  longest_streak  time_began

395        1               2018-12-02 08:56:06.83033-05
399        1               2018-06-10 12:11:18.041521-04
756        2               2018-12-02 19:24:20.880022-05
```

Comment: You should find the solution here, with window functions : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html

Comment: Is a streak interrupted by rows from other players? Also: your version of Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) problem indeed.

**Assuming:**

- "Streaks" are not interrupted by rows from other players.
- All columns are defined `NOT NULL`. (Else you have to do more.)

This should be simplest and fastest as it only needs two fast [`row_number()` window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (player_id)
       player_id, count(*) AS seq_len, min(ts) AS time_began
FROM  (
   SELECT player_id, points, ts
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY ts) 
        - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY player_id, points ORDER BY ts) AS grp
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
WHERE  points = 100
GROUP  BY player_id, grp  -- omit "points" after WHERE points = 100
ORDER  BY player_id, seq_len DESC, time_began DESC;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=656421972aadc9ad92f5fe62378df86c)*

Using the column name `ts` instead of `time`, which is a [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in standard SQL. It's allowed in Postgres, but with limitations and it's still a bad idea to use it as identifier.

The "trick" is to subtract row numbers so that consecutive rows fall in the same group (`grp`) per `(player_id, points)`. *Then* filter the ones with 100 points, aggregate per group and return only the longest, most recent result per player.
Basic explanation for the technique:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35389/3684)

We can use `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT ON` in the same `SELECT`, `GROUP BY` is applied *before* `DISTINCT ON`. Consider the sequence of events in a `SELECT` query:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied/8242764#8242764)

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Answer (score 1):

This is a gap and island problem, you can try to use `SUM` condition aggravated function with window function, getting gap number.

then use `MAX` and `COUNT` window function again.

**Query 1**:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *,
           SUM(CASE WHEN points = 100 THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY time) - 
           SUM(1) OVER(ORDER BY time) RN
    FROM T
)
SELECT player_id,
       MAX(longest_streak) longest_streak,
       MAX(cnt) longest_streak 
FROM (
  SELECT player_id,
         MAX(time) OVER(PARTITION BY rn,player_id) longest_streak, 
         COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY rn,player_id)  cnt
  FROM CTE 
  WHERE points > 0
) t1
GROUP BY player_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b4dfc/15/0)**:

```
| player_id |              longest_streak | longest_streak |
|-----------|-----------------------------|----------------|
|       756 | 2018-12-04T19:57:48.961111Z |              2 |
|       399 | 2018-06-10T12:11:18.041521Z |              1 |
|       395 |  2018-12-02T08:56:06.83033Z |              1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to look at how many rows between the previous and next non-100 results.  To get the lengths of the streaks:

```
with s as (
      select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by player_id order by time) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by player_id) as cnt          
      from scores s
     )
select s.*,
       coalesce(next_seqnum, cnt + 1) - coalesce(prev_seqnum, 0) - 1 as length
from (select s.*,
             max(seqnum) filter (where score <> 100) over (partition by player_id order by time) as prev_seqnum,
             max(seqnum) filter (where score <> 100) over (partition by player_id order by time) as next_seqnum
      from s
     ) s
where score = 100;
```

You can then incorporate the other conditions:

```
with s as (
      select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by player_id order by time) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by player_id) as cnt          
      from scores s
     ),
     streaks as (
      select s.*,
             coalesce(next_seqnum - prev_seqnum) over (partition by player_id) as length,
             max(next_seqnum - prev_seqnum) over (partition by player_id) as max_length,
             max(next_seqnum) over (partition by player_id) as max_next_seqnum
      from (select s.*,
                   coalesce(max(seqnum) filter (where score <> 100) over (partition by player_id order by time), 0) as prev_seqnum,
                   coalesce(max(seqnum) filter (where score <> 100) over (partition by player_id order by time), cnt + 1) as next_seqnum
            from s
           ) s
      where score = 100
     )
select s.*
from streaks s
where length = max_length and
      next_seqnum = max_next_seqnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer

```
select 
user_id,
non_streak,
streak,
ifnull(non_streak,streak) strk,
max(time) time
from (

Select
user_id,time,
points,
lag(points) over (partition by user_id order by time) prev_point,
case when points + lag(points) over (partition by user_id order by time) = 100  then 1 end as non_streak,
case when points + lag(points) over (partition by user_id order by time) > 100  then 1 end as streak


From players
) where ifnull(non_streak,streak) is not null
group by 1,2,3
order by 1,2 
) group by user_id`
```

Comment: Please consider adding a brief explanation of [how and why this solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364). This will help readers to better understand your solution.