# Selecting records that appear several times in a row

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands

My problem is that I would like to select some records which appears in a row.
For example we have table like this:

```
x
x
x
y
y
x
x
y
```

Query should give answer like this:

```
x   3
y   2
x   2
y   1
```

Comment: You'll probably need a second column. Maybe an auto-incredmented id column? Also probably easier in excel if you can't get a second column.

Comment: Please always declare your database system and version. SQL dialects differ heavily.

Comment: The last result row `y|1` disagrees with the title. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your question only makes sense if there is a column that specifies the ordering.  If so, you can use the difference-of-row-numbers to determine the groups and then aggregate:

```
select col1, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by <ordering col>) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by <ordering col>) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by col1, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
```

Comment: Sorry, but there must be something wrong - it shows me that: Incorrect syntax near '*'.

Comment: @beginneeeeer2021 . . . The only `*`s in the query are `count(*)` and `t.*`.  Both are syntactically correct.

Comment: One more question - what is t in 2, 6 and 6 line? :)

Comment: @beginneeeeer2021 . . . That is the table name in the `from` clause and a table alias after the parentheses.  Your question doesn't specify the table name, so I just use `t`.

Answer (score 0):

The elephant in the room is the missing column(s) to establish the order of rows.

```sql
SELECT col1, count(*)
FROM  (
   SELECT col1, order_column
        , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY order_column)
        - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY order_column) AS grp
   FROM tbl
   ) t
GROUP  BY col1, grp
ORDER  BY min(order_column);
```

To exclude partitions with only a single row, add a `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT col1, count(*)
FROM  (
   SELECT col1, order_column
        , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY order_column)
        - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY order_column) AS grp
   FROM tbl
   ) t
GROUP  BY col1, grp
HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER  BY min(order_column);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=86a7175b5b568f39e0df23db9c608f43)*

Add a final `ORDER BY` to maintain original order (and a meaningful result). You may want to add a column like `min(order_column)` as well.

Related:

- [Find the longest streak of perfect scores per player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56583326/find-the-longest-streak-of-perfect-scores-per-player/56584205#56584205)
- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35389/3684)
- [Group by repeating attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010348/group-by-repeating-attribute)

Comment: What is grp here?

Comment: Just alias yes ?

Comment: See `AS grp`? That's the column alias for the computed "group number". Ample explanation in the linked answer. I added another link

Comment: One more question: in 6 and 7th row there should be name of table jest? for example cattable instead od t and tbl? Because I have some error syntax

Comment: `t` in my query is the required alias for the derived table from the subquery. Can be *any* valid identifier. Like `cattable`. `tbl` is a placeholder for the actual name of the underlying table.

Comment: Sorry but it's not what i asked. I was asking: i have table like x x x y y x y y x x y x y. I'm looking for query which gives mi number of names which affected in a row. Here query should give answer: x|3 y|2 y|2 x|2.

Comment: Ah, we can't `ORDER BY grp` as the number is not increasing steadily among different `col1`. Needs to be `ORDER  BY min(order_column)` or similar. Fixed & added fiddle. Assuming PostgreSQL as you won't declare.  The added example in your comment disagrees with the given example in the question. The question *includes* `y|1` in the result.

Answer (score 0):

I made a SQL Fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f8900/5

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SomeTable](
    [data] [nchar](1) NULL,
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO SomeTable
    ([data])
VALUES
    ('x'),
    ('x'),
    ('x'),
    ('y'),
    ('y'),
    ('x'),
    ('x'),
    ('y')
;

select * from SomeTable;

WITH SomeTable_CTE (Data, total, BaseId, NextId)
AS
(
SELECT 
    Data,
    1 as total,
    Id as BaseId,
    Id+1 as NextId
    FROM SomeTable
        where not exists(
            Select * from SomeTable Previous
            where Previous.Id+1 = SomeTable.Id 
            and Previous.Data = SomeTable.Data)
UNION ALL
select SomeTable_CTE.Data, SomeTable_CTE.total+1, SomeTable_CTE.BaseId as BaseId, SomeTable.Id+1 as NextId
from SomeTable_CTE inner join SomeTable on
SomeTable.Data = SomeTable_CTE.Data
and 
SomeTable.Id = SomeTable_CTE.NextId
)
SELECT Data, max(total)   as total
FROM SomeTable_CTE
group by Data, BaseId
order by BaseId
```