# Find the most frequent value per group in a table column

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I need to find most frequent value of `object_of_search` for each ethnicity. How can I achieve this? Subqueries in the `SELECT` clause and correlated subqueries are not allowed. Something similar to this:

```
mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY stopAndSearches.object_of_search) AS "Most frequent object of search"
```

But this does not aggregate and gives me many rows for each ethnicity and object_of_search:

```
 officer_defined_ethnicity | Sas for ethnicity |   Arrest rate    | Most frequent object of search
---------------------------+-------------------+------------------+--------------------------------
 ethnicity2                |                 3 | 66.6666666666667 | Stolen goods
 ethnicity3                |                 2 |              100 | Fireworks
 ethnicity1                |                 5 |               60 | Firearms
 ethnicity3                |                 2 |              100 | Firearms
 ethnicity1                |                 5 |               60 | Cat
 ethnicity1                |                 5 |               60 | Dog
 ethnicity2                |                 3 | 66.6666666666667 | Firearms
 ethnicity1                |                 5 |               60 | Psychoactive substances
 ethnicity1                |                 5 |               60 | Fireworks
```

And should be something like this:

```
 officer_defined_ethnicity | Sas for ethnicity |   Arrest rate    | Most frequent object of search
---------------------------+-------------------+------------------+--------------------------------
 ethnicity2                |                 3 | 66.6666666666667 | Stolen goods
 ethnicity3                |                 2 |              100 | Fireworks
 ethnicity1                |                 5 |               60 | Firearms
```

Table on [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a03a71db40a201e5adfc18350a9948ff).
Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    stopAndSearches.officer_defined_ethnicity,
    count(stopAndSearches.sas_id) OVER(PARTITION BY stopAndSearches.officer_defined_ethnicity) AS "Sas for ethnicity",
    sum(case when stopAndSearches.outcome = 'Arrest' then 1 else 0 end)
       OVER (PARTITION BY stopAndSearches.officer_defined_ethnicity)::float /
       count(stopAndSearches.sas_id) OVER(PARTITION BY stopAndSearches.officer_defined_ethnicity)::float * 100 AS "Arrest rate",
    mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY stopAndSearches.object_of_search) AS "Most frequent object of search"
FROM stopAndSearches
GROUP BY stopAndSearches.sas_id, stopAndSearches.officer_defined_ethnicity;
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stopAndSearches(
    "sas_id" bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    "officer_defined_ethnicity" VARCHAR(255),
    "object_of_search" VARCHAR(255),
    "outcome" VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated: [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5aea8dd166df5ff12f95c0aafad77fb2)

This should address the specific "which object per ethnicity" question.

Note, this doesn't address ties in the count.  That wasn't part of the question / request.

Adjust your SQL to include this logic, to provide that detail:

```
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT officer_defined_ethnicity
             , object_of_search
             , COUNT(*) AS n
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY officer_defined_ethnicity ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rn
          FROM stopAndSearches
         GROUP BY officer_defined_ethnicity, object_of_search
     )
SELECT * FROM cte
 WHERE rn = 1
;
```

Result:

| officer_defined_ethnicity | object_of_search | n | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ethnicity1 | Cat | 1 | 1 |
| ethnicity2 | Stolen goods | 2 | 1 |
| ethnicity3 | Fireworks | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (1)
       officer_defined_ethnicity, object_of_search, count(*) AS ct
FROM   stop_and_searches
GROUP  BY 1, 2
ORDER  BY 1, 3 DESC, 2;
```

Or more explicitly:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (officer_defined_ethnicity)
       officer_defined_ethnicity, object_of_search, count(*) AS ct
FROM   stop_and_searches
GROUP  BY officer_defined_ethnicity, object_of_search
ORDER  BY officer_defined_ethnicity, ct DESC, object_of_search;
```

```
 officer_defined_ethnicity | object_of_search | ct
---------------------------+------------------+----
 ethnicity1                | Cat              | 1
 ethnicity2                | Stolen goods     | 2
 ethnicity3                | Firearms         | 1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4b20dc849f8c7537d687678179583ef1)*

Since **`DISTINCT ON`** is applied *after* `GROUP BY` we only need a single query level.

1. Aggregate to get counts per `(officer_defined_ethnicity, object_of_search)` with `GROUP BY`.
2. Pick the row with the highest count per `officer_defined_ethnicity` with `DISTINCT ON`.

I added `object_of_search` as third `ORDER BY` item to act as tiebreaker and produce a deterministic result:
*In case of ties, pick the first `object_of_search` according to alphabetical sort order.*
Adapt to your needs.

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied/8242764#8242764)

Simpler and typically faster than a subquery with `row_number()`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group? - Benchmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34715134/939860)