# Workaround for FOUND_ROW equivalent in postgreSQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a mysql query shown below. I need to change it to Postgres.  While doing so, I am getting error at `FOUND_ROW()`, there is no such function in Postgres. Could anyone let me know how to handle the function equivalent for the code below?

```
BEGIN
    /*declare temps varchar(2000);*/
    declare tableJoin varchar(2000) default '';
    declare filter varchar(2000) default '';
    declare whereFilters varchar(2000) default '';
    /*set temps = '3';*/
    set @q = '';
    set @join = INSTR(SUBSTRING(filters, 1, INSTR(filters, "=") - 1), ".");
    if @join > 0 then
        /*number of filters*/
        set @count = countCharsInSentence(filters, ',');
        if (@count = 0) then set @count = 1; end if;

        REPEAT
            /*return the filter with a table name*/
            set filter = SPLIT_STR(filters, ',', @count);
            set whereFilters = concat(whereFilters, ',', CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(filter, 1)), substring(filter, 2)));
            /*return the table name*/
            set @filterTable = SPLIT_STR(filter, '.', 1);

            if (@filterTable != '') then
                set @filterTable = CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(@filterTable, 1)), substring(@filterTable, 2));
                set tableJoin = concat(tableJoin, " ", tableName, " join ", @filterTable, " on(", tableName, ".id = ",
                                       @filterTable, ".idRef) ");
            end if;
            /*if(tableJoin!='') then set temps = tableJoin; end if;*/
            set @count = @count - 1;
        UNTIL @count <= 0
            END REPEAT;

        set filters = substring(whereFilters, 2);

        if fields is not null and fields != "" then
            set @q = concat("select id, ", fields, " from ", tableJoin, " where ");
        else
            set @q = concat("select ", tableName, ".* from ", tableJoin, " where ");
        end if;

    else
        /*Define the list of column to be retrieved and set the table name*/
        if fields is not null and fields != "" then
            set @q = concat("select id, ", fields, " from ", tableName, " where ");
        else
            set @q = concat("select * from ", tableName, " where ");
        end if;
    end if;

    set @in = INSTR(filters, " IN (");
    /*Define the where condition to filter the results*/
    if @in > 0 then
        set @where = filters;
    elseif filters is not null and filters != "" then
        set @where = concat(replace(filters, "=", "='"), "'");
        /*set @where = replace(@where, ".", "`.`");*/
        set @where = concat(replace(@where, ",", "' and "));
    else
        set @where = '1=1';
    end if;
    /*set @t = temps;*/
    /*Prepare the query*/
    set @q = concat(@q, @where);

    /*Avoid SQL Injection*/
    set @q = replace(@q, ";", "&#059;");
    /*Execute the query*/
    PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
    execute stmt;
    deallocate prepare stmt;

END ;;
```

I am getting error in Postgres in `FOUND_ROW` as there is no equivalent in pgSQL for it. Can anyone let me know the best alternative that I can put in place of `FOUND_ROW` in my stored procedure?

Comment: There is no `found_row()` in the code you posted, so we cannot see the context. And there is no such function in MySQL either. There is a function [`found_rows()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) though. But it's deprecated. MySQL's documentation suggests to replace it with a query getting `count(*)`. That would also work in Postgres. But there are *a lot* of other things in that code that won't work that way in Postgres...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied/8242764#8242764

Comment: Here [Result Status](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) and the `FOUND` variable? Since you have not actually shown how `found_rows()` is being used in your code it is difficult to get any more specific.

Answer (score 4):

There is no equivalent for MySQL's `found_rows` in Postgres. The `LIMIT` clause stops query execution immediately, so the number of result rows without `LIMIT` remains unknown.

To get the number of returned rows for an embedded query, use [`GET DIAGNOSTICS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) and the `ROW_COUNT` item. Or just use `COUNT(*)`.