# Get rows with maximum count per one column - while grouping by two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, aggregate, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to get max count of a field.
This is what I get and what I'm tried to do.

```
| col1 | col2 |
|  A   |  B   |
|  A   |  B   |
|  A   |  D   |
|  A   |  D   |
|  A   |  D   |
|  C   |  F   |
|  C   |  G   |
|  C   |  F   |
```

I'm trying to get the max count occurrences of `col2`, grouped by `col1`.

With this query I get the occurrences grouped by `col1` and `col2`.

```
SELECT col1, col2, count(*) as conta 
FROM tab 
WHERE 
GROUP by col1, col2 
ORDER BY col1, col2
```

And I get:

```
| col1 | col2 | conta |
|  A   |  B   |   2   |
|  A   |  D   |   3   |
|  C   |  F   |   2   |
|  C   |  G   |   1   |
```

Then I used this query to get max of count:

```
SELECT max(conta) as conta2, col1 
FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2, count(*) as conta 
    FROM tab 
    WHERE 
    GROUP BY col1, col2 
    ORDER BY col1, col2
) AS derivedTable 
GROUP BY col1
```

And I get:

```
| col1 | conta |
|  A   |   3   |
|  C   |   2   |
```

What I'm missing is the value of `col2`. I would like something like this:

```
| col1 | col2 | conta |
|  A   |  D   |   3   |
|  C   |  F   |   2   |
```

The problem is that if I try to select the `col2` field, I get an error message, that I have to use this field in group by or aggregation function, but using it in the group by it's not the right way.

Comment: Does PostGreSQL has specificities for why your second query does not work ? I tried the exact same one (with the missing col2, and without the `WHERE` in the middle and I don't get any error message on MySQL.

Comment: With MySQL is it possible to get field not in a group by, even if there is an aggreation of another field in the select.
In PostgreSQL this is not possible, and if you have an aggregation and other fields in the select, this fields must be in an aggregation themselves or in a group by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler & faster (and correct):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (col1)
       col1, col2, count(*) AS conta
FROM   tab 
GROUP  BY col1, col2 
ORDER  BY col1, conta DESC;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f31c6a5e7532e61ecb4753fd862cf5d9)* (based on a_horse's fiddle)

`DISTINCT ON` is applied *after* aggregation, so we don't need a subquery or CTE. Consider the sequence of events in a `SELECT` query:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied/8242764#8242764)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: Wow thank you so much! It works great and really simpler :)

Answer (score 2):

You can combine GROUP BY with a window function - which gets evaluated **after** the group by:

```
with cte as (
  SELECT col1, col2, 
         count(*) as conta,
         dense_rank() over (partition by col1 order by count(*) desc) as rnk
  FROM tab 
  WHERE ...
  GROUP by col1, col2 
) 
select col1, col2, conta
from cte
where rnk = 1
order by col1, col2;
```

This will return the combination of col1,col2 with the same highest max count twice. If you don't want that, use `row_number()` instead of `dense_rank()`

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1e57be385e52891dcf805e908266017b)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not the most elegant solution, but using a common table expression may help.

```
with cte as (
select col1, col2, count(*) as total
from dtable 
group by col1, col2
)
select  col1, col2, total 
from cte c
where total = (select max(total) 
           from cte cc
           where cc.col1 = c.col1)
order by col1 asc
```

Returns

```
col1|col2|total|
----+----+-----+
 A  | D  |    3|
 C  | F  |    2|
```

[from the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

Comment: Thank you! It works! Just 1 thing more that I'm trying to fix.

Now I have a situation where there is equal total for col1 and col2, and so are selected both row.

How can I keep only the first or the last one?

Answer (score 0):

**I misunderstood the question. Here is your solution:**

```
;with tablex as
    (Select col1, col2, Count(col2) as Count From Your_Table Group by col1, col2),
aaaa as
    (Select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by col1 order by Count desc) as row, * From tablex)

Select * From aaaa Where row = 1
```

Comment: That is the first query I tried but I get only the occurrences. I need the max of the occurrences and also the field col1 and col2.

Answer (score 0):

Using a window function:

```sql
select distinct on (col1) col1, col2, cnt
from 
(
 select col1, col2, count(*) over (partition by col1, col2) cnt 
 from the_table
) t
order by col1, cnt desc;
```

| col1 | col2 | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | D | 3 |
| C | F | 2 |

This solution does not solve cases with ties.

Comment: But that doesn't return `C,F,2`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No, just "to get max count of a field". I was not sure what the OP needs as he also mentions "how can I keep only the first or the last one" which is `C, G, 1`.

Comment: The question contains "*would like something like this*" which includes `C,F,2` - so for each combination of col1,col2 the one with the highest count

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, yes, I overlooked this.  Answer corrected.