# How can I use postgresql count filter with limit without subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query

```
SELECT 
    count(*) filter(where condition) as cond_cnt
FROM table
LIMIT 100
```

But count happening on all table, not respecting LIMIT at all

If I do it with a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    count(*) filter(where condition) as cond_cnt
FROM
(SELECT *
 FROM table
 LIMIT 100
) as sub
```

Then it works fine. What I am missing?

Comment: Remember that in query execution LIMIT is the last thing that runs. Having that in mind, in your first query, 'Limit 100' has no impact as it always returns a single value. But, in the second query, you are first limiting your data set to only 100 rows.

Comment: Yes, that seems right, but is there still a way to avoid subquery?

Comment: Limiting without ordering rarely makes sense.

Comment: Ordering doesn't belong to this question

Comment: @karambaq It would help if you explained why you don't want to use a subquery. You already need one that specifies an `order by` for your desired `filter` clause limit to pick rows predictably, or for that `filter` clause to also support an `order by`.

Comment: A technical alternative would be a CTE. But your logic *does* require a second query. Even in natural language pseudocode, `from the first 100 records of a table (a query) count those that meet a condition (another query)`.

Answer (score 1):

> But count happening on all table, not respecting `LIMIT` at all
> What I am missing?

You are missing the well-defined order of events in a `SELECT` query. `LIMIT` happens *after* window-functions are applied. So you need a subquery or CTE to apply the `LIMIT` first.

See:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied/8242764#8242764)