# Group users by revenue and years

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have problem grouping users in 'Group_3' in 2 consecutive years. Idea is to group users in group 3 that placed orders that are more then 2000 in revenue in 2 consecutive years.

```
SELECT email_id,
       COUNT(*) as num_of_orders,
       SUM(revenue) AS total_money_spent,
       CASE WHEN 
                SUM(CASE WHEN order_creation_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-   31'
                THEN revenue END) > 2000
       THEN 'Group_1'
            WHEN 
                SUM(CASE WHEN order_creation_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' and '2016-12-31'
                THEN revenue END) > 2000
       THEN 'Group_2'
            WHEN 
                SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(years FROM order_creation_date) <> LAG(EXTRACT(years FROM order_creation_date)) 
                OVER(PARTITION BY email_id ORDER BY EXTRACT(years FROM order_creation_date)) + 1 
                THEN revenue END) > 2000
                THEN 'Group_3'
            WHEN 
                SUM(CASE WHEN order_creation_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' and '2016-12-31'
                THEN revenue END) < 2000
       THEN 'Group_4'
            WHEN 
                SUM(CASE WHEN order_creation_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' and '2016-12-31'
                THEN revenue END) = 0
       THEN 'Group_5'
         END
FROM sql_test
GROUP BY email_id
ORDER BY num_of_orders DESC;
```

I get:

> aggregate function calls cannot contain window function calls
> LINE 13: ...E WHEN EXTRACT(years FROM order_creation_date) <> LAG(EXTRAC..

I can't use `LAG` in `CASE` query I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window functions are executed *after* aggregate functions in a `SELECT` statement. You can't nest them in reverse order. Consider the sequence of events:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied/8242764#8242764)

Use a subquery instead:

```sql
SELECT email_id
     , COUNT(*) as num_of_orders
     , SUM(revenue) AS total_money_spent
     , CASE
          WHEN SUM(revenue) FILTER (WHERE order_creation_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31') > 2000 THEN 'Group_1'
          WHEN SUM(revenue) FILTER (WHERE order_creation_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2016-12-31') > 2000 THEN 'Group_2'
          WHEN SUM(revenue) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM order_creation_date) <> last_year + 1)   > 2000 THEN 'Group_3'
          WHEN SUM(revenue) FILTER (WHERE order_creation_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2016-12-31') < 2000 THEN 'Group_4'
          WHEN SUM(revenue) FILTER (WHERE order_creation_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2016-12-31') = 0    THEN 'Group_5'
       END AS my_sum
FROM  (
   SELECT *, LAG(EXTRACT(year FROM order_creation_date)) OVER (PARTITION BY email_id ORDER BY EXTRACT(year FROM order_creation_date)) AS last_year
   FROM   sql_test
   ) sub
GROUP  BY email_id
ORDER  BY num_of_orders DESC;
```

While being at it: aggregate `FILTER` expressions are more elegant & faster than those `CASE` expressions. See:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

Comment: Thank you very much for explenation and code. It helped me understanding window functions !